# Swap contents of two files

Tags: code-golf

This is a code-golf question.  You need to take the contents of two separate files (i.txt and o.txt) and swap them.  You can create a third file to help you with the process, but have your program delete it after the file contents are swapped.  Renaming the files is now allowed again.

Programs must work for any file content.

Shortest code wins, all eligible submissions will be up-voted.

Comment: Rename the files. No need to "take the contents" and swap them to achieve the result.

Comment: @Darren Stone I think that should be illegal.  Thanks for catching that before answers were submitted.

Comment: Looks like a bad constraint, renaming is the best way to do this

Comment: Alright, I can remove this constraint.

Comment: @hdante but 'renaming files' is not _exchanging their contents_. On a system that uses `inode`s the goal here would be for `i.txt`'s `inode` to contain the data from `o.txt`'s `inode`, and vice versa, so that if there are hardlinks to those `inode`s elsewhere, their contents will appear swapped as well. Renaming can't accomplish that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### zsh, 20 + 4 = 24

The script needs to be named `.txt`.

```
(mv [io]$0;>i$0)<o$0
```

or **14** with parameters:

```
(mv $@;>$1)<$2
```

Comment: I like the one without a temporary file better, though: ``i=`<i.txt`;<o*>i*;<<<$i>o*``. It’s too bad this has to be shorter.

Comment: Rules changed to allow renaming files.  You can update your code if you wish.

Comment: You could save 3 chars by replacing `<t>o*;rm t` by `mv t o*` !

Comment: @F.Hauri: Ah, thanks! (There were rules against renaming at one point.)

Comment: This code is not correct. It works only in the special case where i* and o* will match only i.txt and o.txt respectively, i.e. there is no other file with a name beginning with either "i" or "o".

Comment: @ErwanLegrand, that’s not really a special case. Just make a new directory. Alternatively, if what Darren Stone used below is allowed (which it is, according to the asker), simply exchange for `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 77

```
import os;t='.txt';r,i,o,x=[os.rename,'i'+t,'o'+t,'1'+t];r(i,x);r(o,i);r(x,o)
```

## Python, 65

```
import os;t='.txt'
for a,b in zip('iox','xio'):os.rename(a+t,b+t)
```

## Python, 63

```
import os;t='.txt'
for a,b in 'ix','oi','xo':os.rename(a+t,b+t)
```

## PHP, 68

```
<?$r=rename;$t='.txt';$r("i$t","x");$r("o$t","i$t");$r("x","o$t");?>
```

## Windows Batch File, 42

```
move i.txt x&move o.txt i.txt&move x o.txt
```

## Windows Batch File (args), 30

```
move %1 x&move %2 %1&move x %2
```

Comment: I didn't know you can use `$r=rename` to create aliases to functions in PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Two [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) based answers; 52 and 62 chars

### shell: diff + patch (+ tee + sed...) 52

Maybe not the shorter, but I find this fun (and there is no use of *temporary* file):

```
diff -u [io]*|tee >(patch -r -)|sed 1s/i/o/|patch -R
```

Where content is swapped and files are modified **in place**:

#### Sample run

```
swapContent() { diff -u $1 $2|tee >(patch -r -)|sed 1s/$1/$2/|patch -R ;}

while read page file ;do man -Pcol\ -b $page >$file.txt;done <<<$'man i\nbash o'
printf "%s %8d  %s\n" $(join -j 2 <(stat -c '%s %n' [io]*) <(md5sum [io]*))
swapContent [io]*
printf "%s %8d  %s\n" $(join -j 2 <(stat -c '%s %n' [io]*) <(md5sum [io]*))
```

Could produce something like:

```
i.txt    46007  1da1f7533e0eab1e97cce97bb7ca1d3b
o.txt   321071  7dcd230890faf4ef848d4745eda14407
patching file o.txt
i.txt   321071  7dcd230890faf4ef848d4745eda14407
o.txt    46007  1da1f7533e0eab1e97cce97bb7ca1d3b
```

### use of xargs to *simplify* `mv` requests

Not as funny, but nice anyway.

```
set -- {i,o}.txt t&&eval 'xargs -n2 mv<<<"' \${1,3,2,1,3,2} \"
```

Comment: Nota: As first patch output is not redirected, they become garbage on second patch command. This is the reason because only one `patching file o.txt` appear.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 89

I thought I'd give it a shot.

```
<?php $f1='f1.txt';$f2='f2.txt';$ft='ft.txt';copy($f1,$ft);copy($f2,$f1);rename($ft,$f2);
```

Ungolfed version:

```
<?php
$f1 = 'f1.txt';
$f2 = 'f2.txt';
$ft = 'ft.txt';

copy($f1, $ft);
copy($f2, $f1);
rename($ft, $f2);
```

Apparently I took 2 answers of here and combined them.. oh well.

Answer (score 2):

## VBA (148...132) and (126...110)

Renaming with a temp file t in the c:\ drive. Also first attempt at golf :S

```
Sub s():Set f=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"):i="c:\i.txt":t="c:\t":f.MoveFile i,t:f.MoveFile "c:\o.txt",i:Kill t:End Sub
```

If scrrun.dll is referenced already, could cut it down a bit to 126...110.

```
Sub s():Set f=new FileSystemObject:i="c:\i.txt":t="c:\t":f.MoveFile i,t:f.MoveFile "c:\o.txt",i:Kill t:End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like your code has a lot of whitespace. Are you sure they are needed? You can have a much better score if you remove them.

Comment: I don't think it's needed the editor just threw it in. Removed apart from where it's necessary :)

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 72 bytes

Wow! A Ruby code golf! I don't think that's ever been attempted before!

In all reality though, this required some nice Ruby shortcuts and a couple patterns which I found. It was my first golf ever and it was very fun to do. Without further ado, here's the golfed code:

```
3.times{|x|x*=2;t=".txt";a=([?i,?a,?o]*2);File.rename(a[x]+t,a[x+1]+t)}
```

And the ungolfed version

```
3.times do |x|
    x = x * 2
    t=".txt"
    a=([?i,?a,?o]*2)
    File.rename(a[x]+t, a[x+1]+t)}
end
```

The key factor in this is that the parameters passed to the `File.rename` are this, exactly:

```
File.rename "i.txt", "a.txt"
File.rename "o.txt", "i.txt"
File.rename "a.txt", "o.txt"
```

Hope this (doesn't) make sense!

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>44</s> 49 bytes

```powershell
$t='.txt'
ren i$t a$t -fo
ren o$t i$t
ren a$t o$t
```

where `ren` is alias for [Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item). The script uses and delete a third file `a.txt`.

Comment: This can fail with certain encoding. Because `gc` default is UTF8NoBOM but `sc` default is ASCII. Try some UTF-8 files or binary files and you can see how it can fail.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. It need `-e by -n` parameters to ensure that the files unchanged. It would be nice to add a parameter `-readCount 0` to performance. The script with `rename` is shorter :) Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) `--no-lazy`, <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

*-2 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
'°ŽDÀøεS’.í¼t"’«`’File.‚™‚ˆ"ÿ,"ÿ’.E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oYd7hmYf7HjXsPLRJWf3w4kcNuw7vKKtMeNQw0y0zJ1XvUcPCw2s11A/v1zu89tCeEnUdIFNdEyir5wpSNAekSAEoW1JR8qhpzaGlRxccngZkHN0LMng5UAaoRqf2v/qhDUf3uhxuOLzj3NZgkG6waUpA1qHVSHbNetSyCEieblM6vF9HCaQZaM//Woi7yiqRFB6eoYjkKqiDMNxzeDLIURuQ3fL/v65uXr5uTmJVJQA) Link includes a header and footer to create the files and prove that it worked.

```erl
'°ŽDÀøεS’...’«`’...’.E  # trimmed program
      ε                 # for each in...
     ø                  # all characters of...
'°Ž                     # "bio"...
     ø                  # paired with corresponding characters of...
'°ŽD                    # "bio"...
    À                   # rotated left one character...
                    .E  # evaluate...
               ’...’    # "File.rename\"ÿ\",\"ÿ\""...
                        # (implicit) with the first ÿ replaced by...
              `         # second element of...
       S                # list of characters of...
                        # (implicit) current element...
                        # (implicit) with each element...
             «          # concatenated with...
        ’...’           # ".txt"...
                        # (implicit) with the second ÿ replaced by...
              `         # first element of...
        S               # list of characters of...
                        # (implicit) current element...
                        # (implicit) with each element...
              «         # concatenated with...
         ’...’          # ".txt"...
                    .E  # as Elixir code

====================

File.rename  # full program
File.rename  # rename file with name argument 1 to argument 2
```

Comment: Nice answer! `vy` can be `ε` for -1. Also, `í¼t` and `‚™` can simply be `txt` and `re`; the dictionary string and hard-coded string are the same byte-count. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oYd7hmYf7HjXsPLRJWf3w4kcNuw7vKKtMeNQw0y0zJ1XvUcPCw2s11A/v1yupKFHXATLUNYFyeq4gJXNAShQgco@a1hxaenTB4WlAxtG9IGOXA2WAanRq/6sf2nB0r8vhhsM7zm0NVgKpVjq0Gm5FUeqjhlmn25QO71fSARFg4//XQhxTVolwyazDMxThToG6AsMRhyeDXLIB2QH//@vq5uXr5iRWVQIA)

Comment: Oh, and `’.txt’` can be `’.txt"’`, allowing you to drop the `"` after both `ÿ` for another -1: [try it online - **35 bytes**](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oYd7hmYf7HjXsPLRJWf3w4kcNuw7vKKtMeNQw0y0zJ1XvUcPCw2s11A/v1yupKFHXATLUNYFyeq4gJXNAShQgco@a1hxaenTB4WlAxtG9IGOXA2WAanRq/6sf2nB0r8vhhsM7zm0NBukGqlcC0odWw@0pSn3UMOt0m9Lh/TpKIG1AG/7XQtxTVolwzKzDMxThroE6BMMdhyeDHLMB2Q3//@vq5uXr5iRWVQIA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

```
i1="i.txt"
i2="o.txt"
c1=IO.readlines(i2)
c2=IO.readlines(i1)
File.open(i1){|x|x.puts(c1)}
File.open(i2){|x|x.puts(c2)}
```

Shortened version:

```
a=["i.txt","o.txt"]
(0..1).each{|x|b[x]=IO.readlines(a[x])*"\n"}
a.reverse!
(0..1).each{|x|IO.write(a[x],b[x])}
```

Not the shortest, but very simple and easy to read. Also, no intermediate files, only RAM.

Comment: Given that it’s a [tag:code-golf], you could at least take out the spaces and try somewhat for the shortest.

Comment: Totally didn't realize it was code-golf, sorry

Answer (score 1):

### Shell script, 24

Works in Bash and probably most shells.  Pass with your two filenames as parameters.

```
mv $1 ੴ;mv $2 $1;mv ੴ $2
```

If you want fixed filenames then this will do it, for a 12 char penalty:

```
mv i.txt ੴ;mv o.txt i.txt;mv ੴ o.txt
```

Comment: @minitech, yes it does. 'ੴ' becomes 'o.txt'.  Those are `mv` operations, not `cp`.

Comment: Second best answer so far!  Reduce it by two characters and you win! I do not care about fixed filenames.

Answer (score 1):

**Python:**

```
import os
l,e='i_o'*2,'.txt'
for x,y in zip(l,l[1:])[::2]:
 os.rename(x+e,y+e)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Batch File (48)

```
type i.txt>a&type o.txt>i.txt&type a>o.txt&del a
```

I forgot about the move command when I wrote this...

Comment: You just overwrote my `a` file!

Comment: @Danny The question states that you may create another file, but it must be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

### C 162

Golfed: uses t.txt as tmp file and swaps names then removes t.txt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define R(x,y) rename(x,y)
#define X(x) remove(x)
int main(){char *i="i.txt",*o="o.txt",*t="t.txt";R(i,t);X(i);R(o,i);R(t,o);X(t);return 0;}
```

Edit: removed 2 spaces

Answer (score 1):

**PHP** - 172

Golfed version of @EisaAdil's answer

```
$f1='file1.txt';$f2='file2.txt';$f1contents=file_get_contents($f1);$f2contents=file_get_contents($f2);file_put_contents($f1,$f2contents);file_put_contents($f2,$f1contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 45

```php
<?php
copy('i','t');copy('o','i');rename('t','o');
```

Not very golfy but shortest PHP so far.

Comment: file extensions are missing.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol - 46 (rename file) or 55 (r/w contents)

Rename file (using `t` as temporary file):

```
r: :rename 
r i: %i.txt %t
r o: %o.txt i
r %t o
```

Read in then write out file contents:

```
a: read i: %i.txt
b: read o: %o.txt
write o a 
write i b
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy - 99 chars

This is my attempt, with Groovy 2.2.1. I tried to do it without renaming:

```
f={new File(it+".txt")}
w={x,y->x.withWriter{it.write y}}
i=f "i"
o=f "o"
t=i.text
w i,o.text
w o,t
```

Ungolfed:

```
file = { new File(it+".txt") }
writeTextToFile = { x,y -> x.withWriter{it.write y} }

iFile = file("i")
oFile = file("o")

iText = iFile.text
writeTextToFile (iFile,oFile.text)
writeTextToFile (oFile,iText)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C: 65 characters

```c
#define r(a,b)rename(#a".txt",#b".txt");
main(){r(i,)r(o,i)r(,o)}
```

A quite simple solution in C that does the job. It uses a temporary name (`.txt`) for one of the files before giving it its proper new name.

Ungolfed (note how the syntax highlighting fails in the define, a bug has been uncovered!):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define r(a, b) rename(#a ".txt", #b ".txt");

int main()
{
    r(i,  ) // rename("i.txt",  ".txt");
    r(o, i) // rename("o.txt", "i.txt");
    r( , o) // rename( ".txt", "o.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 120 bytes (Contents swapping without file renaming)

```perl
use open IO,':bytes';undef$/;open I,"<i.txt";$I=<I>;open I,"<o.txt";open O,">i.txt";print O<I>;open O,">o.txt";print O$I
```

The file contents is put into memory and written back to the other file. Thus `i.txt` and `o.txt` must fit into memory.

Since the file contents are actually exchanged, hard links are updated automatically, see AJManfield's [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/swap-contents-of-two-files#comment59884_16502).

**Ungolfed:**

```perl
use open IO => ':bytes'; # binmode, not needed for Unix, but needed for Windows
undef $/;                # read whole file instead of lines
open I, "<i.txt";        # open i.txt for reading
$I = <I>;                # read i.txt
open I, "<o.txt";        # open o.txt for reading
open O, ">i.txt";        # open i.txt for writing
print O <I>;             # read o.txt and put the contents in i.txt
open O, ">o.txt";        # open o.txt for writing
print O $I;              # write o.txt with contents of old i.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Batch, 39 bytes

```
ren i.txt x&ren o.txt i.txt&ren x o.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 122 bytes

```
set A [read [open i.txt]]
puts [set i [open i.txt w]] [read [open o.txt]]
puts [set o [open o.txt w]] $A
close $i
close $o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BCsIwDIbveYpQd/Yd5uykIC3owMPoQWaFwjDDVfTtqx0tzrnDcgrJ/@f745rWr4oDzyuOFkux59Abh1eLNXXmhnbtXg6fGrqH6zH7zNmG74REVaIAsaSAy@0gZ9C01JtwBSBBaQSlCKUJlEZQBWpJJaj6Qgl8oORY3835Mv5PR1Id9tPP9Y@e/vTT0BqzPDFtasgPBib5CQslKy6rY4hnWbw0EwnmLTRjian8Gw)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 169 bytes

```
set A [read [set i [open i.txt r]]]
set B [read [set o [open o.txt r]]]
close $i
close $o
puts [set i [open i.txt w]] $B
puts [set o [open o.txt w]] $A
close $i
close $o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BCoMwDIbveYrgPO8d1NUhjBY2YQfpYTgHBVlEO9zbO1sVq/NgTm2S///@6LzsDtGVBSlDhXFyYdAUGl8KM6qKN6qj/mpsJVQf3aDf972QnROOIsYEkj0FjJ/sugd5SU1hXAAmKDlQGqG0gpIDFSD21AQVM5SgM5QAs7p4PDEzn@WZtZTSJgndnWUquzNaqulBQ9INy1ZK9ENnvL6xHwf/fp0VeJzdMRI8ZTy9mWuUNzoN6WZOnwm2JbQhoUHS/QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <del>71</del> 70 bytes

```lua
_ENV=os t='.txt'i,o,r='i'..t,'o'..t,rename r(i,t)r(o,i)r(t,o)remove(t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tc6xCsJADAbg3afIlguk9wDCja6OrnLQDAF7Kbkovn0tVToIji75h//jJ7d7XYYBZtcWqfYuvodatlkaoOZ4BtLRpY6AFYnhh7RvScv1dL4U6xAFt1LZ2Asq5hyMtoVLq5OAJ@UgT8a63mAjl8kekoL@@uNhHf@oZgG7fMPlBQ)

Define `os`, the operating system library, as the global table so we can write `rename` and `remove` instead of `os.rename` and `os.remove`. (Incidentally this also means the one-letter variables are actually fields in the `os` table.) Make short alias for `os.rename` to save some space. Set up filename variables, using `'.txt'` as temporary file. Do the renaming and deleting.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 52 bytes

[AsksAnyway´s php](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16793/55735) modernized & golfed:

```
($r=rename)(i.$e=".txt",x);$r(o.$e,i.$e);$r(x,o.$e);
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>'`.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 66 bytes

```
a=FILENAME,b=!b?a:b{c[a]=c[a]$0RS}END{printf c[a]>b;printf c[b]>a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/0dbN08fVz9HXVSfJVjHJPtEqqTo5OjHWFkSoGAQF17r6uVQXFGXmlaQpgMTskqzhvKRYu8Ta//8B)

Note: I provided a TIO line, but I have no idea how to make it work when the code needs to read from input files?

The rename approaches seem to be much shorter, but here's one in AWK that copies the data instead.  At a high level, it takes a commandline like,

```
gawk '...code...' i.txt o.txt
```

which feeds both files into the program on STDIN. It uses the magic variable `FILENAME` to cache the contents of each one into a separate entry in an associative array.  Then the `END` clause just overwrites each file with the content from the other one.

The "test" per line, which is always truthy, sets `a` to the current filename over and over.  And it also ensures `b` is to the first filename seen.

```
a=FILENAME,b=!b?a:b
```

The code block executed per line, just appends the current line to the accumulated data for the current filename.

```
c[a]=c[a]$0RS
```

Then once all the lines from both files have been read, the `END` code block writes out the files with the content swapped.

```
printf c[a]>b;printf c[b]>a
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
@L
RENAME@OI[2-I],@IO[I]I=I+1GOTO@L
```