# Draw the € sign

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, kolmogorov-complexity, geometry

The goal is to output or display an image with an € (euro) sign according to the following specs (ignoring the border of the sign).

[image: € sign]

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Euro_Construction.svg

Rules:

- The program / script must take the height of the `€` sign in pixels as an argument (empty space around the sign is optional)
- The `€` sign can't be drawn as or from a character, directly (it's forbidden to `print` the `€` in the image) or indirectly (calculating [`8364`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) then displaying it in a HTML page)
- The output does not need to be saved to any file, it can be displayed then just shown as a screenshot
- [Standard “loopholes”](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/14215) are forbidden
- Shortest code wins

Comment: Tricky ! It's time to review my geometry/trigonometry. I see some coordinates quite difficult to deduce.

Comment: I had to look up "facultative"

Comment: Oops, I used a French word by mistake. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: I'm really hoping for a LaTeX + TikZ answer :)

Comment: Without the Euro, this problem wouldn't exist, thereby once again demonstrating the truth of "Mo money mo problems"

Comment: Guys there is a huge issue with this question.... The question should specify **whether or not the result is typographically usable - or whether the result is just a raster (or other) approximation** The two things are of course entirely different. Note that the mathematica answer (while incredibly awesomely clever), is totally unusable. (The result image printed on the screen is, well ... totally wrong! - ask any typographer. There's no point saying "oh maybe if you increase the pixel" .. etc.) At the other extreme the P.S code is (of course) 100% usable typographically.

Comment: I don't know what is *typographically usable* and I'm not a typographer. If you want a perfect € sign, just use the € character. But that's not the goal of this question. I didn't expect pixel perfect images. Feel free to add another question with different rules if you don't like this one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## PostScript/GhostScript, 100

(96 for the program, 4 for the command-line switch prefix)

Fully golfed and hand-tokenized:

```
$ hexdump -C euro.ps
00000000  68 20 88 78 92 36 92 38  92 8b 88 4b 88 3c 92 ad  |h .x.6.8...K.<..|
00000010  88 00 88 00 88 3c 88 2d  88 ce 92 05 88 00 88 00  |.....<.-........|
00000020  88 32 88 d8 88 28 92 06  92 16 88 b9 88 fb 92 6b  |.2...(.........k|
00000030  88 b5 88 f1 92 63 88 13  88 f1 92 63 88 17 88 fb  |.....c.....c....|
00000040  92 63 92 16 88 b9 88 0f  92 6b 88 b5 88 05 92 63  |.c.......k.....c|
00000050  88 1b 88 05 92 63 88 1f  88 0f 92 63 92 16 92 42  |.....c.....c...B|
00000060
```

You can get a copy [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7231cQnKsDQTEcxTTdOa0psSGc/edit?usp=sharing), for your own viewing.

After seeing @ThomasW's answer, and considering my program carefully, I realized that I could do it even better.

The tokenized version is equivalent to this:

```
h 120 div dup scale
75 60 translate

0 0 60 45 -50 arc
0 0 50 -40 40 arcn
closepath

-71 -5 moveto
-75 -15 lineto
19 -15 lineto
23 -5 lineto
closepath

-71 15 moveto
-75 5 lineto
27 5 lineto
31 15 lineto
closepath

fill
```

An explanation of the optimizations:

First off, I converted my first solution into a union of some simpler subpaths, rather than one path circumscribing the entire thing. I borrowed Thomas's method of inputting a parameter, which is much better than what I had had.

Then I multiplied all the coordinates by 10 and rounded everything off to give me just integer coordinates. I also rounded off the angles, and converted the two large ones to equivalent negative angles. This conveniently makes every single number fall between -128 and 127.

And then I tokenized *everything*. Each operator can be represented with a two-byte sequence each. And because each number can be represented by a single signed byte, each one *also* becomes only two bytes. The only part I couldn't do that with was the `h` at the start, but it too is only two bytes, just the `h` and a space after it.

Run it as:

```
gs -dh=200 euro.ps
```

[image: 200 pt high]

```
gs -dh=80 euro.ps
```

[image: 80 pt high]

```
gs -dh=20 euro.ps
```

[image: 20 pt high]

---

### New: Even shorter versions!

Using encoded user paths, I have managed to reduce the program size by a few bytes. Each of these programs is equivalent to the first one, producing identical output:

92 bytes:

```
hexdump -C euro.ps
00000000  68 20 88 78 92 36 92 38  92 8b 88 4b 88 3c 92 ad  |h .x.6.8...K.<..|
00000010  7b 7b 88 b5 88 c4 88 2d  88 3c 30 20 30 88 3c 88  |{{.....-.<0 0.<.|
00000020  2d 88 cf 30 20 30 88 32  88 d8 88 28 88 b9 88 fb  |-..0 0.2...(....|
00000030  88 b5 88 f1 88 13 88 f1  88 17 88 fb 88 b9 88 0f  |................|
00000040  88 b5 35 88 1b 35 88 1f  88 0f 7d 8e 0b 00 07 08  |..5..5....}.....|
00000050  0a 01 23 03 0a 01 23 03  0a 7d 92 b3              |..#...#..}..|
0000005c
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
h 120 div dup scale
75 60 translate
{
 {-75 -60 45 60
  0 0 60 45 -50
  0 0 50 -40 40
  -71 -5
  -75 -15
  19 -15
  23 -5
  -71 15
  -75 5
  27 5
  31 15}
  <00 07 08 0A 01 03 03 03 0A 01 03 03 03 0A> 
} ufill
```

And a slightly counterintuitive confusing solution saves one more character, for only 91:

```
$ hexdump -C euro.ps
00000000  68 20 88 78 92 36 92 38  92 8b 88 4b 88 3c 92 ad  |h .x.6.8...K.<..|
00000010  5b 5b 8e 1e b5 c4 2d 3c  00 00 3c 2d ce 00 00 32  |[[....-<..<-...2|
00000020  d8 28 b9 fb b5 f1 13 f1  17 fb b9 0f b5 05 1b 05  |.(..............|
00000030  1f 0f 7b 92 38 88 7f 92  50 7b 32 35 36 92 a9 7d  |..{.8...P{256..}|
00000040  92 54 7d 92 49 5d 92 32  8e 0b 00 07 08 0a 01 23  |.T}.I].2.......#|
00000050  03 0a 01 23 03 0a 5d 92  32 92 b3                 |...#..].2..|
0000005b
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
h 120 div dup scale
75 60 translate
[
  [
   <b5 c4 2d 3c
    00 00 3c 2d ce
    00 00 32 d8 28
    b9 fb
    b5 f1
    13 f1
    17 fb
    b9 0f
    b5 05
    1b 05
    1f 0f> {dup 127 gt {256 sub} if} forall 
  ] cvx
  <00 07 08 0A 01 23 03 0A 01 23 03 0A> 
] cvx
ufill
```

Comment: Great work! I guess I'll have to learn *all* about binary tokens.

Comment: @ThomasW. Although I'm not completely done yet; I am still reading through the encoded path strings documentation...

Comment: You don't need the space after `h` because binary tokens are self-delimiting. BTW, how did you code it? I did it with a standard hex editor, which is tedious.

Comment: @ThomasW. Really? For some reason it was causing trouble for me.

Comment: `0 0` in ASCII is only three bytes while it's four in binary. Likwewise the single digit 5s are shorter than the two byte binary ones.

Comment: @ThomasW. Oh well. I will be posting a _much_ shorter version soon anyway.

Comment: @ThomasW. Well, I wasn't ablw to shorten it that much, but it is shorter now. Too bad there aren't integral homogenous number arrays, or I could save another 26 bytes.

Comment: I didn't know about tokenizing files. Can you edit the `.ps` tokenized file? Is it really a program source file if you can't edit it? In other words, if you send me this tokenized `.ps` file, assuming I know Postscript, will I be able to alter the shape of the sign without the un-tokenized file?

Comment: @n.1 tokenized files work exactly the same as regular PostScript files, and you can even mix binary tokens and standard plaintext PostScript in the same file. Each binary token corresponds directly to an operator or other object, so you can easily replace or insert operations, or even copy snippets to another program. The exact details about the tokenized form can be found in the [PostScript Language Reference Manual](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) (the red book) in section 3.12. Encoded user paths are described in 4.6.2.

Comment: Do you need a special text-editor to edit the tokenized script? I opened the downloaded `.ps` with Geany (a text-editor) but I only see asian characters: `栠衸鈶鈸銋衋蠼銭蠀蠀蠼蠭裎鈅蠀蠀蠲裘蠨鈆鈖袹裻鉫袵裱鉣蠓裱鉣蠗裻鉣鈖袹蠏鉫袵蠅鉣蠛蠅鉣蠟蠏鉣鈖鉂`

Comment: @n.1 I used a hex editor to write the file, for that reason. The token delimiter bytes normally correspond to control characters in ISO-latin-1 and other fixed-width encoding, but if the editor is interpreting it in UTF-8 or another variable-width encoding, you will get stuff like that, same with any other file that includes binary data.

Comment: @AJMansfield: I was able to open the `.ps` file with [wxHexEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5512594/2257664), thanks.

Answer (score 50):

### Mathematica, <s>193</s> <s>183</s> <s>177</s> <s>173</s> <s>169</s> 166 bytes

Yay, maths! I'm plotting the region that satisfies a certain (rather complicated) set of inequalities:

```
e=RegionPlot[(1<Abs@y<3||c)&&{x,y+12}.(d=2{-5Sin@40°-6,m=5Cos@40°})*{x+15,y+1-2Sign@y}.d<0||c&&x<2m/.c->100<x^2+y^2<144,{x,-15,9},{y,-12,12},Frame->0>1,ImageSize->#]&
```

Usage is `e[height]`, e.g. `e[100]`:

[image]

Or `e[200]`:

[image]

You may notice, that the sharper edges are slightly rounded off. That's because the region can only be plotted by sampling the points in space, and Mathematica doesn't sample each pixel by default. The sampling resolution can be increased by adding another option  `PlotPoints->#` (which uses one sample per pixel), which adds **14 characters**. I don't recommend running it with that option, because it significantly increases runtime and barely increases visual appeal beyond `#/4` or so. Hence, (after approval of the OP) it is not included in the score.

Here is a slightly ungolfed version:

```
e[height_] := (
  angle = 40°;
  d = {-5 Sin[angle] - 6, 5 Cos[angle]};
  RegionPlot[
      (Abs[y] > .5 && Abs[y] < 1.5
        ||
       r > 25 && r < 36)
    &&
      {x, y + 6}.d > 0
    &&
      {x + 7.5, y + .5 - Sign[y]}.d < 0
    ||
      r > 25 && r < 36 && x < 5 Cos[angle] 
    /. r -> x^2 + y^2
    ,
    {x, -7.5, 4.5},
    {y, -6, 6},
    Frame -> False,
    ImageSize -> height
  ]
);
```

Note that in the golfed version, I've scaled the coordinate system by a factor of 2 to avoid the `.5`s, but it turns out that the character count is actually identical.

Here is an explanation for how I worked out the formula. I divided the shape into two regions. One contains the ring and the stripes and is cut off to the right with the `BCDE` slope and to the left with the `IJ` and `GH` slopes (more on that later). The other contains the same ring, but is simply cut off at the *x* coordinate of point `D`. The conditions for the two regions are combined with `||`, which acts as a set union here.

The ring is just defined as `5 < r < 6`, where `r` is the distance from the origin. `r²` is easier to work out though (`x²+y²`), so I'm using `25 < x² + y² < 36` to get all the points in the ring.

The stripes are between `±.5` and `±1.5`. We can handle both stripes at the same time, by taking the modulus of *y*, so the stripes (of infinite length) just fulfil `.5 < |y| < 1.5`. Again, to take the union of the stripes and the ring, I'm just using `||`.

The interesting thing is probably how to get the "masks" though. Point `D` has an *x* coordinate of `5 cos 40°`, so the mask taking care of lower edge (combined with the ring only) is just `x < 5 cos 40°`. This can be applied via set intersection which translates to `&&` in logic.

The other masks are the really tricky part. First, let's get the slope of `BCDE`. We can easily construct points `C` and `D`, as `(0, -6)` and `5 (cos 40°, sin 40°)`, respectively. The vector pointing along the line is then just `D - C = (5 cos 40°, 5 sin 40° + 6)`. To apply the mask on the right, I only need to figure out if a point lies to the left or the right of that line (let's call line vector `p`). I can figure this out by taking the vector from `C` to my point of interest and projecting it onto a vector *perpendicular* to `p`. The sign of the projection will tell me the side the point is on. Obtaining the perpendicular vector is pretty simple in 2D: flip the coordinates and reverse the sign of one of them. That's the variable `d` in my code: `(-5 sin 40° - 6, 5 cos 40°)`. The vector from `C` to a point of interest `q = (x, y)` is `q - C = (x, y + 6)`. The projection is just the scalar product (or dot product) between `q` and `d`. The way I chose `d` it happens to point to the left, so I want `d.(q-C) > 0`. This condition applies the right-hand mask.

For the left-hand mask I can use basically the same idea. The slope is the same and therefore so is `d`. I just need offset my point from the lower-left corners of stripes instead of from `C`. Those have coordinates `(-7.5, 0.5)` (upper stripe) and `(-7.5, -1.5)` (lower stripe). So that would call for two independent rules for the two stripes. However, note that all points affected by the lower mask are in the lower stripe and hence have negative *y*. And all points affected by the upper mask have positive *y*. So I can simply switch my offset using `Sign[y]` which is `1` for positive and `-1` for negative `y`. So my offset point becomes `(-7.5, -0.5 + Sign[y])`. Otherwise the mask works just like the right-hand mask. Of course, this time the projection needs to be negative. So, naively that would be something like `RH-projection > 0 && LH-projection < 0` (which is also what I originally had in the code). But we can shorten this, because multiplying a positive and a negative number has to give a negative number, so it's just `RH * LH < 0` (where `RH` and `LH` are the respective projections).

That's it. Putting it all together leads to the following logical structure:

```
(
  (is_in_circle || is_in_stripe)
  &&
  is_between_left_and_right_mask
)
||
(
  is_in_circle && left_of_edge
)
```

Just to be clear, the coordinates in my explanation refer to the construction diagram given in the challenge. As mentioned above my code actually multiplies all of them by `2` - I changed it to save bytes, but the byte count is actually identical, and I couldn't be bothered to revert the change again. Also integers look nicer.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Mathematica, so I'd appreciate some comments on your code!

Comment: @ThomasW. well, the actual Mathematica stuff is just a call to `RegionPlot` which simply colours in all points in space that satisfy a given condition. So giving it `x^2+y^2<1` will draw a unit circle. I'll add an explanation for the actual maths though (later tonight).

Comment: What is the length of the code with not rounded edges? I think you have the shortest code at this moment, but I can't accept your answer with the rounded corners, it would be unfair to the other answers which have not rounded corners. Please follow strictly the specifications. Thanks

Comment: @n.1 Unless you're disqualifying Thomas W.'s PostScript answer, because it's binary or because it's rounded too aggressively, his answer is definitely shorter. However, fixing the resolution takes 14 characters, so my answer is still the shortest after his. I'll edit.

Comment: @ThomasW. there you go!

Comment: @m.buettner : since you have most votes, the other users didn't see any problem with the rounded edges. So I will forget it and accept that this is an € sign. :-)

Comment: @n.1 So should I reduce my score by 14 again?

Comment: @m.buettner : I looked at your edits but didn't see that you added 14 to the score. Yes, you can subtract 14 from your score.

Answer (score 29):

## BBC BASIC, 202

```
INPUTh:w=h/12s=w/2.4p=25VDU22,6,29,640;400;p,4,0;1.5*w;p,153,6*w;0;p,4,0;1.5*w;p,159,h/3.1;4.7*w;p;9*s;9*w;p,87,h/3.1;-19*w;p,4,-7.5*w;0;p;s;w;p,85,4.5*s;0;p,81,s;w;p;s;w;p;s;w;p,85,-7.5*w;2*w;p,81,s;w;
```

download emulator at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

**In BBC basic, all graphics are handled at the low level using machine-specific ASCII control characters** (but some high level commands are also available for the common ones for convenience.) The ones used here are 22 (change display mode) 29(change origin) and 25, equivalent to the PLOT statement, which takes an additional action parameter (draw line, circle, triangle, etc. in background/foreground with relative/absolute move) before the X and Y parameters.

**So all I have to do is send a load of characters to the VDU controller.** values terminated in semicolon are 16 bit. others are 8 bit. **The total number of bytes sent to the VDU controller is 91**, though that in itself would not qualify as an answer because by that stage the size is hardcoded.

The obvious place for the origin is the centre of the circle, but there are actually more commands involved in producing the bars. So I shifted the origin down 1.5 to the bottom of the lower bar, which reduces the number of fractions and negative numbers required. It remains on the vertical line with the centre of the circle, which is important because the line E starts from this vertical line.

Actually, I only had to calculate 3 numbers off the drawing: the top inner corner of the C shape (5 cos 40, 5 sin 40 + 1.5) = (3.8302,3.1394+1.5) = approx (12/3.1, 4.6) and the gradient of the line E:x/y=3.8302/(6+3.1394)=0.4157 = approx 1/2.4

As I only have the free evaluation version (interpreted), I take the symbol height as user input. If you buy the full version (29.99GBP) you can compile and then read the command line with `w=VAL(@cmd$)/12`.

**Ungolfed code**

In the golfed code, there is only one VDU statement, but in the ungolfed code I break it down into several for clarity. Also, because BBC basic is little endian, the combination `p,0,` can be golfed to `p;` but I left it ungolfed for clarity.

```
  INPUT h
  w=h/12                   :REM w is the width of the line, which is 1/12 the height of the symbol, hardcoded at 900.
  s=w/2.4                  :REM s/w is the gradient x/y of line E. s is the horizontal offset of the top and bottom of the ends of horizontal bars
  p=25                     :REM VDU p,action,x;y; is the equivalent of PLOT action,x,y

  VDU 22,6                 :REM change mode
  VDU 29,640;400;          :REM set origin

  VDU p,4,0;1.5*w;         :REM move to centre of circle
  VDU p,153,6*w;0;         :REM draw circle in foreground colour
  VDU p,4,0;1.5*w;         :REM move to centre of circle
  VDU p,159,h/3.1;4.6*w;   :REM draw circle in background colour, ending at the upper inner point of the C shape.
  VDU p,0,9*s;9*w;         :REM move relative along slant gradient, 9 spaces in y direction, to define the upper cut on the circle
  VDU p,87,h/3.1;-19*w;    :REM draw triangle in background colour, based on the last two points and the absolute point specified here (vertical line for lower cut)

  VDU p,4,-7.5*w;0;        :REM move absolute to bottom left of lower bar
  VDU p,0,s;w;             :REM move relative to top left of lower bar
  VDU p,85,4.5*s;0;        :REM draw triangle to bottom right corner of lower bar (absolute)
  VDU p,81,s;w;            :REM draw triangle to top right of lower bar (relative)

  VDU p,0,s;w;             :REM move relative to bottom right of upper bar
  VDU p,0,s;w;             :REM move relative to top right of upper bar
  VDU p,85,-7.5*w;2*w;     :REM draw triangle to bottom left of upper bar (absolute)
  VDU p,81,s;w;            :REM draw triangle to top left of upper bar (relative)
```

[image]

Comment: BBC BASIC. Awesome! This takes me back almost thirty years!

Comment: @Dommer BBC Basic was first released in 1981, more than 20 years before the first Euro notes were printed (2002.) So this is the only way you could have drawn a large euro sign on such a machine! Alternatively you could redefine ASCII character `n` to a euro symbol with an 8x8 bitmap, like this: `VDU 23,n,30,33,120,32,120,30,30,0`. According to Wikipedia, BBC Basic is still being developed, mainly for mobile devices.

Comment: Indeed! I think we got ours in 1984. I remember drawing cool sprites on graph paper and then working out their binary representations, as I'm sure you have done too. On which note, I just drew out your Euro symbol by hand. It's very good once the typo is fixed and the antepenultimate value is changed from 30 to 33. I see from your profile you have also used LOGO which again takes me back to my primary school days. It's great to learn BBC Basic is still in use today. If it was good enough for us...

Comment: Just to add, the BBC Basic 8x8 bitmap could be made more "italic" (in keeping with the larger logo) by changing it to `VDU 23,n,30,33,124,32,120,33,30,0`. Thanks for the trip down memory lane.

Answer (score 25):

## HTML, <s>250</s> <s>249</s> <s>248</s> <s>242</s> <s>244</s> <s>234</s> 229

```
<svg viewBox=-7.5,-6,12,12
onload=this.style.height=prompt()><clipPath
id=c><path
d=M5-6,1.8,1.5,3.8,3.2V6H-9.4L-7.1,.5-7.5-.5-5.2-6>
</clipPath><g
clip-path=url(#c) fill=none stroke=#000><circle
r=5.5 /><path
d=M-8,1h15M-8-1h15>
```

While this is only using SVG stuff, it heavily relies on lax HTML parsing and has to be served as HTML.  Strict SVG would require a lot more bytes.

[Try it!](http://jsbin.com/quwuyibuqa/edit?html,output)

Comment: (-: ǝɯ oʇ ǝuıɟ sʞoo⅂

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in PostScript coordinates, which are the other way round!  Swapped the y axis now.

Comment: Work for me (Chrome 34) even without the trailing `</svg>`. Oh, and that markup is *horrible*. I hope you're ashamed of yourself. ;-)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I *am* ashamed ;-). Usually I even prefer clean XHTML over HTML. Anyway, if I leave away the trailing `</svg>`, I only see the circle not the lines (in a standalone file, not inside the markup JS Bin might add).

Comment: You can shorten `evt.target` to `this`, saving 6 bytes.

Comment: @toothbrush Thanks! Included that.

Comment: -8 bytes using `onload='this.style.height=prompt()'` works in FF and Chrome

Comment: @nderscore Thanks for your help! It's even 10 bytes without the quotes.

Comment: Without the quotes, Firefox doesn't prompt :(

Comment: @nderscore Interesting!  For me it does (FF 29/Linux).

Comment: Seems it was because I was testing it without the linebreaks.

Comment: To save a byte you can change `#000` to `red`.

Comment: It's 2 years later, but I was grabbing this demo as an extreme example of the difference between the HTML & XML parsers & discovered that the trailing `</svg>` is just confusing matters.  All you need is a closing `>` for the path. The `</svg` part is getting parsed as part of the path data attribute.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Ah, thanks for spotting this. No idea why I didn't close the path tag. This explains why [in one comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26689#comment-59230) I stated I didn't see the horizontal lines without the closing `</svg>`.

Comment: Yep, without at least one `>`, the parser just throws out the final, incomplete tag.

Comment: Oh, there is [a recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnGIw7CK7pQ&t=724s) of @AmeliaBR's talk featuring this nasty piece of code. Hope your work on SVG 2 soon gets to the state of a final recommendation after all those years!

Answer (score 17):

### CSS, <s>512</s> 494 bytes

```
<style>*,:after,:before{position:absolute;width:20;content:"";background:#fff}#a{margin:150;height:20;border:2px solid;border-radius:20px}#a:after{width:10;height:10;bottom:0;right:-8}p{top:7;left:-6;width:29;height:2;border:solid;border-width:2 0;transform:skewX(-23deg);margin:0;background:0}p:before{width:2;height:4;bottom:-3;left:-.5}p:after{width:16;height:16;bottom:-3;right:-8}</style><div id=a><p><script>document.getElementById('a').style.transform='scale('+(prompt()/24)+')'</script>
```

Not the smallest answer by a fair bit, but as small as I could get even when summoning all my css-minification-fu

### Caveats:

The above code with all 'px' stripped works in Firefox & IE but not Chrome & Safari which are fussier about their units :)

I also had to re-add the px's to get the jsfiddle to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/9A3J9/

100:
[image]

200:
[image]

### ungolfed code:

```
 <style>
*,:after,:before{
    position:absolute;
    width:20;
    content:"";
    background:#fff
}
#a{
    margin:150;
    height:20;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:20px
}
#a:after{
    width:10;
    height:10;
    bottom:0;
    right:-8
}
p{
    top:7;
    left:-6;
    width:29;
    height:2;
    border:solid;
    border-width:2 0;
    transform:skewX(-23deg);
    margin:0;
    background:0
}
p:before{
    width:2;
    height:4;
    bottom:-3;
    left:-.5
}
p:after{
    width:16;
    height:16;
    bottom:-3;
    right:-8
}
</style>

<div id=a><p>

<script>
document.getElementById('a').style.transform='scale('+(prompt()/24)+')'
</script>
```

Comment: Wow! That `skewX` trick could get my upvote alone.

Comment: that's exactly what I started writing yesterday. false points to you then

Comment: setting an id on the div and using `getElementById` reduces 6 char. and then you can use the id in the css to reduce 2 more

Comment: also, the `p` closing tag can be omitted if there is no more content after it (by spec). and i'd check also if the browsers autoclose the `div` (altough forbidden by spec, it worked in the fiddle on FF)

Comment: @einacio great suggestions! we're down to 494 B. thanks :)

Answer (score 16):

## PostScript+Ghostscript 137 + 6 = 143 (binary), 209 + 6 = 215 bytes

Fully golfed version with binary tokens:

```
$ hexdump -C euro_golfed.ps 
00000000  68 20 31 32 20 92 36 92  38 92 8b 37 2e 35 20 36  |h 12 .6.8..7.5 6|
00000010  92 ad 35 20 36 0a 31 2e  38 20 2d 31 2e 35 0a 33  |..5 6.1.8 -1.5.3|
00000020  2e 38 20 2d 33 2e 32 0a  33 2e 38 20 2d 36 0a 2d  |.8 -3.2.3.8 -6.-|
00000030  39 2e 34 20 2d 36 0a 2d  37 2e 31 20 2d 2e 35 0a  |9.4 -6.-7.1 -.5.|
00000040  2d 37 2e 35 20 2e 35 0a  2d 35 2e 32 20 36 92 6b  |-7.5 .5.-5.2 6.k|
00000050  37 7b 92 63 7d 92 83 35  2e 35 92 14 30 92 6f 2d  |7{.c}..5.5..0.o-|
00000060  38 20 2d 31 0a 2d 38 20  31 92 6b 32 7b 31 35 20  |8 -1.-8 1.k2{15 |
00000070  30 92 85 92 6b 7d 92 83  30 20 30 20 35 2e 35 20  |0...k}..0 0 5.5 |
00000080  30 20 33 36 30 92 05 92  a7                       |0 360....|
00000089
```

[Download hand coded binary file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/w5zd2lws1tql5j8/euro_golfed.ps)

ASCII version:

```
h 12 div dup scale
7.5 6 translate
5 6
1.8 -1.5
3.8 -3.2
3.8 -6
-9.4 -6
-7.1 -.5
-7.5 .5
-5.2 6
moveto
7{lineto}repeat
clip newpath
5.5 0
-8 -1
-8 1
moveto
2{15 0 rlineto moveto}repeat
0 0 5.5 0 360 arc
stroke
```

Save as `euro.ps` and run with Ghostscript like

```
gs -dh=80 euro.ps
```

[image: Euro sign, 80 points, rendered by Ghostscript]

```
gs -dh=20 euro.ps
```

[image: Euro sign, 20 points, rendered by Ghostscript]

As there is no such thing as a pixel in PostScript, that height is interpreted in points instead. I calculated +6 for the switch on the command line.

Comment: Meh, how am I supposed to beat the compiled file size. :D ... How do those binary tokens work? Isn't it basically like compiling the code by hand?

Comment: `DC` line doesn't cut horizontal stripes correctly. Perpendicular down from `D` doesn't cut 'circle' shape at the right place, lower :(. Looks like same is with your SVG answer, too.

Comment: + Left edges of horizontal stripes are not aligned.

Comment: @m.buettner The most important PostScript names can be expressed using a two byte sequence. This is not really compiling like you would compile a C or Java program. It will go through the same parsing process as any PostScript program. If you look at the hexdump or open the binary file in a text editor you can see that it's almost the same as the ASCII version, but most names were replaced by a two byte sequence.

Comment: @VadimR You have a sharp eye! I guess I traded too much of the precision for brevity (rounding too aggressively).  I might have to add some digits.

Comment: @VadimR Thanks for the hints, I actually miscalculated one point and dropped a tenth digit.

Comment: If `A` is `0,0`, then where mask intersects lower stripe, `y = -1.5` therefore `x = 1.5/tan40` i.e. 1.7876... not 1.8. If `E` has `y = 6`, then `x = 12*5*cos40/(6+5sin40)` i.e. 4.9883... not 5. It's visible if scaled up to 1000 px or more - `DC` line still doesn't cut stripes where expected. I mean, if no irrational numbers are hard-coded (moreover rounded), then picture is scalable to whatever size with no distortions. Sorry, it's only my nagging, - please ignore.

Comment: I wrote another even smaller postscript solution [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26916/7981).

Answer (score 13):

## PHP, <s>432</s> <s>435</s> <s>367</s> <s>356</s> 334 bytes

<sub>(Edit: Apparently IJ and GH are supposed to be parallel with BCDE. Now fixed)</sub>

This script outputs an SVG image, but will serve it as `text/html` by default. I think most browsers will treat this as an HTML web page containing an embedded SVG image. It seems to work OK for me anyway.

The height of the image is passed as a query string parameter. (Note: the byte count includes a newline character at the end of line 3, which is necessary for this to work properly).

```
<?php $x=$_GET['x']/12;$a=$x*5;$b=$x*6;$c=$x*7;$d=$x*12.4884;$e=$x*2.2863;$f=$x*5.5;$g=$x*.4157;$h=$x*6.5;$i=$x*7.5;$j=$x*12;$k=$x*11.3302;$l=$x*9.1628;$m=$x*8;$s=$x*12;echo<<<Q
<svg width="$s" height="$s"><clipPath id="c"><path d="M$d 0H$e L0 $f L$g $h L0 $i V$s H$k V$m H$l z"/></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#c)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="$x"><circle cx="$i" cy="$b" r="$f"/><path d="M0 $a H$k M0 $c H$k"/></g></svg>
Q;
```

---

#### Updated version (<s>367</s> <s>356</s> 334 bytes):

`preg_replace_callback()` is a much more efficient way of scaling the numerical values. This code produces the same output as the original version. (Edit: Further reductions thanks to [Einacio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13870))

```
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback('/[\d\.]+/',function($m){return$m[0]*$_GET['x']/12;},'<svg width=12 height=12><clipPath id=c><path d=M12.4884,0H2.2863L0,5.5,0.4157,6.5,0,7.5V12H11.3302V8H9.1628z /></clipPath><g clip-path=url(#c) fill=none stroke=black stroke-width=1><circle cx=7.5 cy=6 r=5.5 /><path d=M0,5H11M0,7H11 /></g></svg>');
```

### Output:

**euro.php?x=60**

[image]

**euro.php?x=200**

[image]

Comment: `width` and `height` are unnecessary here. And you need to specify the `xmlns` for it to render in most browsers (tested Firefox and Chrome; even with SVG's proper MIME type sent, they both render it as XML, not SVG). http://ideone.com/JkqVL0 (remove the hardcoded x value for a 369 byte solution)

Comment: @TimS. No, it won't work properly if you run the PHP code at ideone and copy the results to an SVG file. But if you actually publish the script on a web server, PHP will (by default) serve the results with a MIME type of `text/html`. Chrome and Firefox have no problems with this, although I just discovered that Safari is a bit more pernickety.

Comment: Ah! I see the trick now: `text/html` with `<svg>...` is interpreted as an HTML file with an `svg` element, which doesn't need the `xmlns` but does need `width` and `height`. I was thinking in terms of an SVG file, which needs the proper `xmlns`. Your code is fine.

Comment: on the second code, if you use 24 instead of 12, wouldn't you reduce 1 byte on each x.5 value?

Comment: @Einacio Yes! :-) Unfortunately I also gain a byte at each occurrence of "5", "6", "7" and "8". The resulting length is exactly the same.

Comment: bummer.
since the svg is interpreted as an html, you do not need the attributes to be xml well-formed. thus, you can remove the quotes on attributes with simple values (width, height, cx, cy, r, fill, stroke, id, stroke-width). but r should be `r=5.5 />` with an space so the slash is not counted as attribute value

Comment: @Einacio That seems to work. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 13):

## Python - turtle - 517

```python
import turtle,sys
from math import *
q=sqrt
h=int(sys.argv[1])/24
t=turtle.Turtle()
z=t.begin_fill
y=t.end_fill
x=t.goto
w=t.towards
v=t.fd
u=t.circle
r=t.seth
o=t.setx
n=t.xcor
t.pu()
x(10*h,0)
t.left(90)
t.circle(10*h,40)
z()
A=w(0,-12*h)
B=2/sin(A*pi/180)
u(10*h,280)
r(-90)
C=n()/h
v((q(144-C*C)-q(100-C*C))*h)
D=w(0,0)
r(D+90)
u(-12*h,D+135.42)
y()
F=2*pi/9
G=h*cos(F)/(5*sin(F)+6)
x(45*G,-3*h)
z()
o(-15*h)
r(A)
v(B*h)
o(45*G+15*h+n())
y()
x(65*G,h)
z()
o(-15*h)
r(A)
v(B*h)
o(65*G+15*h+n())
y()
t.ht()
input()
```

`python % 100` and `python % 500` respectively:
[image] [image]

Comment: You could save a lot of characters by getting rid of a few of the shortcuts you define. You only use `c` once, so it would actually be shorter to just invoke it as `math.cos`, and I think there are probably others that you could unabbreviate to cut overall length.

Comment: You can shave off six characters by using `from math import *` then dropping the `math.` prefixes.

Comment: You define `u=t.circle`, but a few lines later you forgot to swap out a `t.circle(...)` call.

Comment: Turtle to draw the €. What a time to be alive.

Answer (score 9):

### sh, 8604

I *think* someone can probably do better, but let’s start this off.

```
echo 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|base64 -d|unxz>e.svg;echo \<img src=e.svg height=$1\>>e.htm;firefox e.htm
```

Comment: Wouldn't that come under the standard loophole of hard-coding the output?

Comment: @AlexThornton It does take an input though.

Comment: This definitely falls under the "standard loopholes" category.

Comment: @Igglyboo: How so?

Comment: This is a very long answer for a code-golf challenge. :-)

Comment: @Igglyboo Disagree.  .svg is vector-based so can be infinitely scaled - and is by the `$1` input parameter.

Comment: @minitech I borrowed/stole your technique, but golfed it down with a much smaller .svg http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26733/11259

Answer (score 9):

## HTML5, 395

[**==> Try it online**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvpf7/)

```html
<canvas id=c><script>_='function e,t,n){c.savtranslate,trotatn?0:.42)}v=docuEleById("c"c=vContex"2d"scalw=(v.width=v.height=promp))/12,w76,1arc(56--114.2,6,66-13,6.-   2,1 11.5)c.clearRec2restor-7mov-71lin6,.5,strokt(   .5--e(0,);1,ment.geteTo(';for(Y in $='  ')with(_.split($[Y]))_=join(pop());eval(_)</script>
```

The code is compressed using [JSCrush](http://www.iteral.com/jscrush/).

Here is the uncompressed code :

```html
<canvas id=c>
<script>
v=document.getElementById('c');
c=v.getContext('2d');
function r(){c.rotate(0.42)}
function t(x,y){c.save();c.translate(x,y)}
c.scale(w=(v.width=v.height=prompt())/12,w);
t(7.5,6);
c.arc(0,0,5.5,0,6);
c.stroke();
c.moveTo(-7.5,-1);c.lineTo(6,-1);
c.moveTo(-7.5,1);c.lineTo(6,1);
c.stroke();
c.clearRect(4.2,0,6,6);
t(0,6);r();
c.clearRect(0,-11,3,6.2);
c.restore();
t(-7.5,-0.5);r();
c.clearRect(-1,-2,1,2);
c.restore();
t(-7.5,1.5);r();
c.clearRect(-1,-1.5,1,1.5)
</script>
```

Comment: This can be reduced to 378 by golfing the source before applying crush: http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/EUBG8/

Comment: This is JavaScript, not HTML. I am tired of people not understanding how that works.

Comment: Yeah, because `<canvas>` tag is JavaScript... HTML5 is often used to not write HTML/CSS/JS. Not that people don't understand it, programmers are just often lazy (at least I am). Your comment seems a bit harsh.

Comment: @Mig I thought HTML+CSS+JS was called DHTML?

Answer (score 6):

## PostScript, 270

```
7 7 translate
/l{lineto}def
/o{0 0}def
o 6 44.85 165.52 arc
-7.08 1.5 l
-7.5 .5 l
o 6 175.22 184.74 arc
-7.08 -.5 l
-7.5 -1.5 l
o 6 194.48 309.67 arc
o 5 320 197.46 arcn
1.87 -1.5 l
2.29 -.5 l
o 5 185.74 174.26 arcn
2.7 .5 l
3.12 1.5 l
o 5 162.54 40 arcn
closepath fill
```

This just defines the outline by appending path elements based on coordinates I calculated with the help of GeoGebra, and then fills the outline.

I saved a few chars by adding shortcuts for `lineto` (`/l{lineto}def`) and the origin of the circle (`/o{0 0}def`).

To specify a different size, add a command of the form `height width scale` after the first blank line.

When run on its own, this draws the euro sign in the bottom left-hand corner of the page of the default page size. Just save it as `anything.ps` and view it with a document viewer.

Here is an image of it at the default size, rasterized to a little over 90 pixels per inch:

[image: default size at 90 ppi]

At 4x size:

[image: 4x size at 90 ppi]

You can also [download the original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7231cQnKsDQc3IyMnVhbzBSajQ/edit?usp=sharing) for your own viewing pleasure.

Comment: Does it read any argument to define the size of the sign?

Comment: @n.1 oh, sorry, I didn't read that part of the spec. I'll fix it after dinner.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the rendered file.

Comment: @n.1 I have added images.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP (without SVG), <s>628</s> 597 bytes

Thanks to [AsksAnyway](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16793/10619) for the nice shortcut for functions (e.g. `$c = print; $c('Hello world!');`).

```php
<?php header('Content-type:image/png');$h=$_GET['h'];$i=imagecreatetruecolor($h*1.1,$h*1.1);$c=imagecolorallocate;$b=$c($i,0,0,0);$w=$c($i,255,255,255);imagefill($i,0,0,$w);$l=$h*.7;$t=$h*.55;$u=$h/12;$e=imagefilledellipse;$e($i,$l,$t,$h,$h,$b);$e($i,$l,$t,$h*5/6,$h*5/6,$w);$f=imagefilledpolygon;$f($i,array($l+$u*5,$t+$u*1.5,$l-$u*7.5,$t+$u*1.5,$l-$u*7.125,$t+$u*0.5,$l+$u*4,$t+$u*.5,$l+$u*4,$t-$u*.5,$l-$u*7.5,$t-$u*.5,$l-$u*7.125,$t-$u*1.5,$l+$u*5,$t-$u*1.5),8,$b);$f($i,array($l+$u*4.24,$t-$u*4.24,$l+$u*1.84,$t+$u*1.5,$l+$u*3.84,$t+$u*3.26,$l+$u*3.84,$t+$u*4.62,$h*2,$t,),5,$w);imagepng($i);
```

Call `file.php?h=200` from your browser in order to see the image

The coordinates are based on measurements performed with GIMP

### 100 pixels:

[image: € 100 pixels]

### 200 pixels:

[image: € 200 pixels]

### Layers added step by step:

[image: # GIF]

### Ungolfed code (with fractions, the golfed code has rounded values)

```php
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');

$h = $_GET['h'];

$i = imagecreatetruecolor($h * 1.1,$h * 1.1);

$c = imagecolorallocate;

# black
$b = $c($i,0,0,0);
# white
$w = $c($i,255,255,255);

imagefill($i,0,0,$w);

$l = $h * .7; # distance between left and center of the circle
$t = $h * .55; # distance between top and center of the circle

# one "unit", as defined by the specs
$u = $h / 12;

$e = imagefilledellipse;
# disk is black
$e($i, $l, $t, $h, $h, $b);
# inner disk is white
$e($i, $l, $t, $h * (5 / 6), $h * (5 / 6), $w);

$f = imagefilledpolygon;
# draw 2 bars in black
$f($i, array(
# bottom bar
$l + $u * 5, $t + ($u * 1.5), # bottom right
$l-$u * 7.5, $t + ($u * 1.5), # bottom left
$l-$u * 7.125, $t + ($u * 0.5), # top left
$l + $u * 4, $t + ($u * 0.5), # top right
# top bar
$l + $u * 4, $t - ($u * 0.5), # bottom right
$l-$u * 7.5, $t - ($u * 0.5), # bottom left
$l-$u * 7.125, $t - ($u * 1.5), # top left
$l + $u * 5, $t - ($u * 1.5) # top right
), 8, $b);

# hide right parts of bars and circle by drawing white
$f($i, array(
$l + $u * 6 * (212 / 300), $t - ($u * 6 * (212 / 300)), # right of the disk
$l + $u * 6 * (92 / 300), $t + ($u * 6 * (74 / 300)), # left = bottom right of bottom bar
$l + $u * 6 * (191 / 300), $t + ($u * 6 * (163 / 300)), # bottom of the circle
$l + $u * 6 * (191 / 300), $t + ($u * 6 * (231 / 300)), # bottom of the circle too
$h * 2, $t, # some point at the right of the image (outside the image)
), 5, $w);

imagepng($i);
```

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + ImageMagick + linux command-line tools, 460 bytes

```
base64 -d<<<H4sIADBMaVMAAy1Ru27DMAz8FUJdBVsk9QziLFo8uD/QrUDSOIDTBo1Rt39fUsl0POp0PEr7+88Zfq/L530w87redn2/bVu3cff1fe7JOdeLwsB2Oa7zYDw7A/Ppcp5XJWQO+9v7OsN9/VtOg/m4LMvuRS4ZOA7m1VkseQpBoQZvyXlQQPeA2JpEjVEGURL7EePkLCU3Rqw5Wo4EmLALVgaC9BUrk392OAWt0HUBPHrb+NQq4i5UzigeSU6Zsii5xOYiWLE0BCT1Z89QVKLD2dPEIbdEBasINWIDaiDxG2BjslpBXXTk5CeWFkYa1a2KuS0OMBfJ8RgdKzMr03DRP5Ojy5O8sE2ksdU1g+pcu+SqvILUWddNCBHbCIxvpj/s9ZsO/xXfC57OAQAA|zcat|convert -scale $1 svg:- png:-|xview stdin
```

This is the same technique as @minitech's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26714/11259).  But the .svg data comes from here, which is much shorter: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Euro_symbol_black.svg.  ImageMagick converts the vector data to .png data at the requested scale and pipes to xview.

Output for `./euro.sh 30`:

[image]

Output for `./euro.sh 300`:

[image]

Comment: Why is the large version not filled?

Comment: how can you output images to stdin?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You cannot "output" to standard input. He's just sending a load of characters to `base64`, which is a program, which decompiles it into binary tokens (representing an svg file, apparently), with which he does more stuff.

Comment: @tomsmeding I believe they were confused by the window title being "stdin".

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think neither version filled, but on the small version the inner and outer lines are rendered close enough to appear solid.  Having said that there is clearly some weird aliasing thing going on with ImageMagick that I don't fully understand - but I think the generated image is close enough for code-golf ;-)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc `png:-` tells ImageMagick to output a .png-formatted stream to stdout, instead of to a file.  This is piped to xview.  The `stdin` option tells xview to read data streamed from stdin instead of from a file.

Comment: Can you explain why the biggest version is not filled? That's strange that the small one is but not the largest one.

Comment: The `./euro.sh 300` is too tall (the height of the image is 600 pixels)

Answer (score 3):

## POV-Ray (370 bytes)

I couldn't figure out how to render the same vertical area and preserve the aspect ratio at the same time, so I decided to go for the correct height and its up to the user to render only in 4:3 format

```
camera{angle 9 location 102*z right x*8 up y*6 look_at 0}
light_source{99*z color 1}
plane{z,0 pigment{color rgb 1}}
#declare b=difference{box{<-5,-.5,1>,<8,.5,1>}box{-2,2 rotate-67*z translate 9.4*x}}
difference{union{torus{5.5,.5 rotate 90*x}object{b translate y}object{b translate -y}}box{<-3.83,-5,-3>,<-7,0,3>}box{<0,7,3>,<-4,-2,-3>rotate 23*z translate-2.5*x}}
```

run with `povray.exe /RENDER euro.pov -w600 -h800`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Processing, 232 bytes

Processing doesn't really allow taking in command line arguments since it is so specialized for drawing, but my function takes in the parameter as height to compensate.  Coordinates are hard-coded/approximated from the image above, and the entire canvas is scaled based on the input parameter to get drawings of arbitrary sizes.

```
void E(int h){scale(h/12,h/12);noFill();strokeWeight(1);arc(7.5,6,11,11,0.7,PI*2-0.7,OPEN);noStroke();fill(0);shearX(-PI/6);rect(3.2,4.5,9,1);rect(4.4,6.5,8,1);shearX(PI/6);fill(255);rect(11,6,9,6);triangle(8.75,6,12.25,6,12.25,0);}
```

## Ungolfed + entire program

```
void setup()
{
  size(575, 500);
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  E(height);
  noLoop();
}

void E(int h)
{
  scale(h/12,h/12);
  //Main "C"
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(1);
  arc(7.5,6,11,11,0.7,PI*2-0.7,OPEN);
  //settings for other shapes
  noStroke();
  //the two bars
  fill(0);
  shearX(-PI/6);
  rect(3.2,4.5,9,1);
  rect(4.4,6.5,8,1);
  //bottom cut of "C"
  shearX(PI/6);
  fill(255);
  rect(11,6,9,6);
  //top cut of "C"
  triangle(8.75,6,12.25,6,12.25,0);
}
```

## Output

[image: Processing Euro sketch]

Comment: You can golf by using `1` instead of `OPEN` as well changing the `255` in the `background` and `fill` calls to `-1`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (MinGW), <s>277</s> 276 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat

Added `-lm` compiler flags to TiO for illustrative purposes, but MinGW does not need it.

Outputs a 3-shade PGM file to STDOUT.

```c
q,i,c;main(s,v)char**v;{float u=atoi(v[1])/12.,d,r;q=u*15;for(*v=memset(calloc(q,q+1),2,i=q*q);i--;i[*v]-=d<6&d>5|r>6&r<7|r>8&r<9&&r<7|c<q/2+u*3.83&&u*31.538-s>r*u|r>10&&u*7-s<r*u&&u*9-s<r*u|r<8)r=i/q/u,c=i%q,d=hypot(q/2-c,q/2-r*u)/u,s=2.405*c;printf("P5 %d %d 2 %s",q,q,*v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7RioMwEEV/RQpKkk7UaG0tMX7Dvpc@SKxtQGuTaGDZ7q9vNu7CMOfemcswkt6l9F6DAsmnTj2RBYflozOEOP41jHO3RKvollkhd2FXnLEihR4M12IlrOLDbBBxYrpN9rYg2Y3jLJEGvWcYClBCE425opSrC3FXKvrmmPRt9TbtMTHNKbAOPCd/RjY6K/YrKdO6TJJAllZlTW1ryBqSLN@GJ2qb4Dd5/pdv09TYCJXpbAUpVKyhF4/P17ygcI9K2HrI4bC2okgPeUUkfxn1XAa0@6iiuN@qiGK7g/A7EIf5t/e@yPMfOYzd3Xo6Tr8)