# Display the Hacker Logo

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, grid, game-of-life

You may have heard of the "Hacker Logo", also called the "Hacker Emblem". It looks like this:

[image: hacker logo]

This is a pattern from a mathematical simulation called the Game of Life. The glider is the simplest Life pattern that moves, and the most instantly recognizable of all Life patterns.

## The challenge

The challenge is pretty simple: Display the hacker logo. This is defined as:

- A 3x3 grid with a border, a white background and gray gridlines.
- Five black dots arranged in the GoL glider pattern.
- Nothing else.

## The rules

- The black dots must fill **40%**-**80%** of their individual grid-boxes.
- You will display the emblem with graphical output but **no ASCII art**.
- The output must be at least **30x30 pixels**.
- The output must only have the colors **gray, black and white**.
- Each grid-box in the grid will be the same size. The grid will be a **regular 3x3 square**.
- You may not pull the logo from the internet or your filesystem.
- Your program will display the logo on an empty screen/window. If it terminates it must do so normally.
- Note that "dots" does not necessarily mean "circles". A "dot" is a single geometric shape centered in the middle of the grid-box with one surface. For example, while a circle or square will qualify as a dot, two triangles or a checkerboard will not.

## The winner

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in each language wins!

Please include a screenshot of the output of your program in your answer.

Comment: I had no idea this was called the Hacker Logo. I have used it as my avatar on some sites, guess that makes me a Hacker.

Comment: @MarkThomas that or a GoL nerd xD

Comment: Is it acceptable to use black gridlines?

Comment: @Octopus `gray gridlines.` Nope, sorry. That would make it a bit too easy.

Comment: What does "**clear the screen**" mean? Is it okay if it displays it in a window?

Comment: @DavidConrad "clear the screen" means if you're using an IDE/interface that has builtin graphics you can't display it with existing text on the screen. Yes, you can display it in a window.

Comment: Is multiple shades of gray (and related off colors) due to anti-aliasing allowed?

Comment: Do we have to display the output or can we return it or save to a file?

Comment: The last sentence of the rules is a bit unclear. Is it supposed to say that triangles or checkerboards will **not** qualify?

Comment: Should the borders be single-lined? See most HTML solutions that use tables below.

Comment: @Gieron Oops, I missed that from a previous revision of the post. Thanks.

Comment: `■◙■\n■■◙\n◙◙◙` is a no-go :P?

Comment: Could you clarify if "The black dots must fill 40%-80% of their individual grid-boxes" means: (1) that 40-80% of the pixels of a box's white fill should become black by drawing a dot; or (2) that the width of the dot should be 40-80% of the width of the white fill? (a 40% area dot is deceptively big).

Comment: @JonathanAllan The first one.

Comment: @IanMiller Yep, by "gray" I didn't mean any specific color, I meant "generic gray".

Comment: @TheLethalCoder `Display the hacker logo`

Comment: @carusocomputing Nope :P

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Could you clarify what you mean by "single-lined"?

Comment: @MarkThomas : [http://catb.org/hacker-emblem](http://catb.org/hacker-emblem) (which I recognize to be the "home page" for the emblem) would say that by using this logo (e.g., as your avatar), "you are visibly associating yourself with the hacker culture. This is not quite the same thing as claiming to be a hacker yourself".  Thank you for being a friend to this culture.

Comment: "and the most instantly recognizable of all Life patterns." Not me. To me the 5x5 infinite growth is more recognizable. Also, I love CGoL.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Mathematica, 62 bytes

```
Grid[{{,a=██,},{,,a},{a,a,a}},Frame->All,FrameStyle->Gray]
```

[image]

## Mathematica, 71 bytes

```
Grid[{{,l=Graphics@Disk[],},{,,l},{l,l,l}},Frame->All,FrameStyle->Gray]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can save bytes by using a pure function with `Graphics@Disk[]` as an argument.

Comment: If you mean this Grid[{{,#,},{,,#},{#,#,#}},Frame->All,FrameStyle->Gray]&@Graphics@Disk[]   it is 72 bytes

Comment: A 69 byte variant on this: `Rasterize@Grid[{{,●,},{,,●},{●,●,●}},Frame->All,FrameStyle->Gray]`. The ● is a two byte unicode character. As it doesn't have to strictly be a circle perhaps some ASCII character could work to meet the 40%-80% requirement.

Comment: actually I made it to 62 bytes meeting all requirements

Comment: I think you need `Rasterize` or similar to meet the requirement of `graphical output but no ASCII art` as the symbols are still selectable in the grid as Unicode characters.

Comment: OP's words (see main comments):"By "no ASCII art" I meant you couldn't draw the entire thing in ASCII. I didn't mean you can't use Unicode characters :P "

Comment: I though Mathematica had a `Glider` builtin for this, seeing as Stephen Wolfram loves cellular automata so...

Answer (score 36):

## CSS+HTML, <s>56+84=140 bytes</s> 52+84=136 bytes

Saved 4 bytes by incorporating suggestions from the comments.

```css
td{border:1px solid#888;line-height:.4;font-size:3em
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0><tr><td><td>•<td><tr><td><td><td>•<tr><td>•<td>•<td>•
```

This uses the UTF-8 character `•` which is 2 bytes long and takes advantage of the graciousness of HTML syntax.

Comment: Not bad; that's pretty clever using `•`!

Comment: I could alternatively set `border:1px solid#888` which isn't exactly `gray` but it saves a byte because it omits the space.

Comment: By "gray" I didn't mean the HTML builtin color for gray, I meant... generic gray. `#888` is fine.

Comment: Very cool. I think you could save a byte with `line-height:.4;`, and another by omitting the closing `}`

Comment: You could save 1 byte with: `font-size:3em`

Comment: Doesn't using • count as ASCII art, which is against the challenge rules?

Comment: Are the double borders (internal, Chrome) according to the rules?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd It doesn't say you can't do that, so... yes?

Comment: @Hankrecords not sure; OP said it was clever, and ASCII art usually involes ASCII, which `•` is not (`•` is unicode but not ASCII)

Comment: @StephenS Sounds like a really futile distinction, plus I don't see the sense in banning ASCII art but allowing unicode art. As for the OP saying it was clever, my comment was in fact directed to the OP, I forgot to put in the @.

Comment: @StephenS By "no ASCII art" I meant you couldn't draw the entire thing in ASCII. I didn't mean you can't use Unicode characters :P

Comment: You can save characters by making the grey border 4px, and ditching the `font-size`. Then it meets the size requirements. (It's a bit ambiguous in the description whether the gridlines are counted in the 40-80% requirement. I'm assuming they're not.)

Comment: The only Code Golf answer I _ever_ understood, at least I do believe so.

Comment: [I zoomed the result](https://prnt.sc/ff3at7) on my display (Firefox, possibly flawed), I count cells of 19*21 = 399 pixels. Of those, I count 261 white pixels (rendered red in the picture for easy counting). So that's (399 - 261) / 399 = 34.58% of covered area. And therefore I believe this answer doesn't meet the criteria. In short, the dots are too small.

Comment: Well if it's OP-approved (OPproved?) +1 then :) but @MDXF please edit your question to make it clearer, someone else might misunderstand that rule as I did

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by removing `1px `

Answer (score 26):

## GLSL (fragment shader), <del>278</del> <del>235</del> 256 bytes

```
precision highp float;void main(){vec2 a=gl_FragCoord.xy/20.-.2;ivec2 b=ivec2(a);a-=vec2(b)+.5;if(b.x>2||b.y>2)discard;gl_FragColor=a.x<-.5||a.y<-.5||a.x>.3||a.y>.3?vec4(.5,.5,.5,1.):length(a+.1)<.4&&(b.x+b.y-3)*b.y==0?vec4(0.,0.,0.,1.):vec4(1.,1.,1.,1.);}
```

[image]

See it in action: http://glslsandbox.com/e#40717.2

Comment: Hmm... does the border go all the way around the graphic? Also, are you sure the circles are only 80% of the grid-boxes?

Comment: A circle that touches all four sides of its enclosing square fills a proportion π/4 of the square, or about 78.5%.

Comment: I reduced your code's size to 222 bytes:
`precision highp float;void main(){vec2 a=gl_FragCoord.xy/20.-.2;ivec2 b=ivec2(a);a-=vec2(b)+.5;gl_FragColor=vec4(vec3(a.x<-.5||a.y<-.5||a.x>.3||a.y>.3?.5:length(a+.1)<.4&&(b.x+b.y-3)*b.y==0?.0:1.)*float(b.x<3&&b.y<3),1.);}`

Answer (score 25):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>169 140</s>  137 bytes

```python
from turtle import*
up()
shape("square")
color("gray",[1]*3)
i=9
while i:i-=1;goto(20-i/3*20,i%3*20-20);stamp();209&2**i or dot(15,0,0,0)
```

Actual size, 61 by 61, plotted within a much larger canvas of 300 by 400:

[image: actual size]

Showing the pixel grid:

[image: pixel grid version]

The dots use 177 pixels within the range of 40%-80% whether considering the 19 by 19 white fill (144.4-288.8) or the 21 by 21  including both borders (176.4-352.8).

*Note:* the program terminates and closes the canvas window as soon as the drawing has been finished, to allow manual window closure append the line `done()`.

`turtle` is a Python package developed for introductory graphical programming. A pen starts at `x,y=0,0` in the middle of a 300 by 400 pixel canvas (by default), `up` lifts the pen, `goto` moves the pen, `shape` sets the shape of the pen to a named shape (`"square"` is a predefined shape with a default pixel-width of 21), `color` sets the colour, where two parameters set stroke (with default a width of 1) and fill; a byte is saved by using the `(r,g,b)` tuple option to replace `"white"` with `[1,1,1]` using the list multiplication `[1]*3`. Finally `dot` draws a dot with the given width in pixels and colour. The dot's default width value is too small to qualify, as is `9` so I made it an aesthetic and qualifying `15`. The dot's colour could be `"black"` but the unpacked `(r,g,b)` tuple of `0,0,0` is shorter by two bytes.

The pen must move away from any dot at the end since otherwise the gray/white pen hides the dot.

The grid is traversed using a div (`/`) and mod (`%`) of `i` starting at `8` (`i` is initialised to `9` but is decremented at the beginning of the `while` loop) and working down to `0`, offsetting the results of `2,1,0` to `-1,0,1` using `(1-...)` and scaling each up to the grid size using a factor of 20 (note that `20-i/3*20` is actually a byte less than `20*(1-i/3)`, same goes for `%`). This produces the order [bottom-left, centre-left, top-left, bottom-middle, centre-middle, top-middle, bottom-right, centre-right, top-right], and requires a "`hasDot`" evaluation of `[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]`, which is `302` in binary so may be accessed by inspecting the `i`<sup>th</sup> power of two component of `302` with using a bitwise-and, `302&2**i`. This can then be inverted to `209&2**1` enabling the use of `or` rather than `and`.

Comment: Very good approach and much shorter than I thought would be possible using `turtle`.

Answer (score 15):

## HTML & CSS, 155 bytes

Turns out HTML is ***really*** forgiving about syntax errors.

<sub>*1 byte saved thanks to @Octopus* · *1 byte saved thanks to @Downgoat* · *2 bytes saved thanks to @StephenS*</sub>

<sub>*2 bytes saved thanks to @Ryan* · *3 bytes saved thanks to @styfle* · *4 bytes saved thanks to @Ferrybig*</sub>

<sub>*13 bytes saved thanks to @SteveBennett*</sub>

```css
p{height:33px;width:33px;border-radius:50%;background:#000;margin:0
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 border=1><td><td><p><td><tr><td><td><td><p><tr><td><p><td><p><td><p
```

Comment: You can save quite a few bytes by removing the `td` CSS definition, and changing the `<table>` to `<table cellspacing=0 border=1 ...`. The output is slightly different, but it looks close enough to my eyes. *shrug*

Comment: Weirdly, I can replace most of the `<div>` to `<p>` and it works, but if I replace *all* of them, it doesn't. Particularly the one in the top row - if I change it, they all disappear. Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit), OSX.

Comment: It actually looks like a bug in Chrome. In the inspector, if I disable one of the style properties, and re-enable, the table gets redrawn correctly.

Comment: @SteveBennett thanks! about the `p` thing, I've tried it before, doesn't work on my chrome 59.. (circles get ellipse shape)

Comment: `border=1` will be correct and save two bytes over `border=1px`.

Comment: To get `p` to look good, you have to add `;margin:0` which adds 9 bytes but saves you 12 bytes over `div` so a net of 3 bytes saved.

Comment: You don't need the first `<tr>`, saving another 4 bytes

Answer (score 14):

## [Applesoft BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applesoft_BASIC), <s>479</s> <s>476</s> <s>516</s> <s>515</s> <s>483</s> 482 bytes

<sup>-32 by using unreadable variable names :P</sup>
<sup>-1 because Apple decided to be magical and let me use an implicit/nonexistent GOTO</sup>

Here is my own (very beatable) program for an example of an output that does not use circles:

```
1GR:POKE49234,0:COLOR=15:FORI=0TO39:VLIN0,47ATI:NEXT:COLOR=5:S=21:W=S:H=27:X=INT((40-W)/2):Y=INT((48-H)/2):D=INT(W/3):DX=D:C=Y+H:G=X+W:FORI=0TO3:VLINY,C ATX+I*D:NEXT:D=INT(H/3):FORI=0TO3:HLINX,G ATY+I*D:NEXT:YH=INT(D/2):Z=Y+H-YH:XH=INT(DX/2):COLOR=0:FORI=0TO2:B=Z:A=X+XH+I*DX:GOSUB5:NEXT:B=B-D:GOSUB5:B=B-D:A=A-DX:GOSUB5:K=PEEK(-16384):IFK<128THEN2:K=PEEK(-16368):TEXT:HOME:END 
5VLINB+2,B-3ATA:VLINB+2,B-3ATA-1:VLINB+2,B-3ATA+1:VLINB+2,B-3ATA+2:VLINB,B-1ATA-1:VLINB,B-1ATA+2:RETURN
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this is valid, since line 1, being longer than 239 characters, is impossible to enter by normal methods, at least on a //e.

Comment: @insert_name_here You have to save it to a file on a disk.

Answer (score 14):

## IA-32 machine code, <s>81</s> 80 bytes

Hexdump:

```
60 8b f9 b8 50 35 20 20 ab b8 32 35 36 20 ab ab
ab fe 4f fe 33 c9 66 49 51 8a c1 d4 55 50 8a c5
d4 55 5b b2 80 84 c0 74 1f 84 db 74 1b b2 ff 2c
10 3c 35 77 13 93 2c 10 3c 35 77 0c 8d 0c 58 8a
cd b0 e4 d2 e0 79 01 42 92 aa 59 e2 cb aa 61 c3
```

It's a `fastcall` function called `doit` that returns the image in PGM format in the supplied buffer. Usage:

```
char buf[256 * 256 + 256];
doit(buf);

FILE* f = fopen("k.pgm", "wb");
fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, f);
fclose(f);
```

Output:

[image: hacker's logo]

I used 256x256 resolution because <s>it's cool</s> it lets me split the pixel's index in `ecx` automatically into coordinates `y` in `ch` and `x` in `cl`. Also, the PGM file format requires the number 255 in the image header.

The inner squares are 54x54 (41% of the cell by area).

Source code (can be compiled by Visual Studio):

```
    pushad;                 // save all registers
    mov edi, ecx;           // edi is now the pointer to output
    mov eax, '  5P';        // PGM file header
    stosd;                  // store it
    mov eax, ' 652';        // the number 256 and a space
    stosd;                  // store the width
    stosd;                  // store the height
    stosd;                  // store maximum brightness
    dec byte ptr [edi-2];   // fix maximum brightness to 255

    xor ecx, ecx;           // initialize the counter of pixels
    dec cx;                 // to 65535
myloop:
    push ecx;

    mov al, cl;             // al = cl = x coordinate in the image
    _emit 0xd4;             // divide by 85
    _emit 85;               // ah = x cell number, al = x coordinate in cell
    push eax;
    mov al, ch;             // al = ch = y coordinate in the image
    _emit 0xd4;             // divide by 85
    _emit 85;               // ah = y cell number, al = y coordinate in cell
    pop ebx;                // bh = x cell number, bl = x coordinate in cell

    mov dl, 0x80;           // gray pixel value
    test al, al             // is cell boundary (y)?
    je output1;
    test bl, bl;            // is cell boundary (x)?
    je output1;

    mov dl, 255;            // white pixel value
    sub al, 16;
    cmp al, 53;
    ja output1;             // if outside the inner square, output white
    xchg eax, ebx;          // exchange the registers to shorten following code
    sub al, 16;
    cmp al, 53;
    ja output1;             // if outside the inner square, output white

    lea ecx, [ebx * 2 + eax]; // cell index = y * 2 + x
    mov cl, ch;
    mov al, 0xe4;           // load the bitmap for the glider pattern
    shl al, cl;             // shift the needed but into SF
    jns output1;            // the bit was 0? - output white
    inc edx;                // the bit was 1? - change to black

output1:
    xchg eax, edx;
    stosb;                  // output the byte

    pop ecx;
    loop myloop;
    stosb;                  // output an additional gray pixel
    popad;
    ret;
```

The cell pattern

```
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 1
```

can be represented by an "optimized" bitmap of 7 bits.

The bits are indexed by the expression `y * 2 + x`, where `(x,y)` is the location of the cell. This expression gives the same index to 2 pairs of cells. It's a lucky coincidence that the bit values there are the same.

Comment: This is cool, but I make `42*42/85/85` only 24.4%.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: The white parts of the cell are only 84x84, but yes, a 42x42 box is only a quarter of a 84x84 box.

Comment: I've asked for clarification (if it does go to area I hope it's not too hard to update).

Comment: The ruling is in - it's area...

Comment: I enlarged the black dots from 42 to 54. It's the minimum, making them 40% by area, and they have already started being ugly...

Comment: @The_Server201 suggested `mov cl, al; or cl, bl; je output1;` instead of `test al, al je output1; test bl,`

Comment: @StephenS This logic doesn't work - it's like using `if !cond0 && !cond1` while I need `if !cond0 || !cond1`

Comment: @anatolyg OK :) I had it in suggested edits, didn't want to send it through, but wanted to inform you of it

Answer (score 13):

## PNG, <s>105</s> 100 bytes

[image: PNG image]    (i.e. this image file)

Considering that HTML and other [non-programming languages are allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/8478),
I was curious to see how much I could golf a plain browser-displayable image, to serve as a baseline comparison.
The result is compressed with the open-source tools [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net) (`-o7 -zm1-9 -strip all`)
and [pngwolf](https://github.com/jibsen/pngwolf-zopfli).
I also experimented with [zopflipng](https://github.com/google/zopfli), but the results were bigger.
Other closed-source compression tools might be able to shave off a couple more bytes.

Image data in base64:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAAA
fCAAAAAA6xUnlAAAAK0lEQVR42mM4gB8wHPgPAwf+M0DAf4TYqDwp
4Ydp0qg8ofBDqMXKGpXHDwDDq0qBspApTgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAAA
    fCAAAAAA6xUnlAAAAK0lEQVR42mM4gB8wHPgPAwf+M0DAf4TYqDwp
    4Ydp0qg8ofBDqMXKGpXHDwDDq0qBspApTgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

**Edit** I made the dots touch the cell top and bottom, to cause more repetitiveness in the pixel pattern and thus improve the compression ratio.
But don't worry, a dot still only fills (7*9)/(9*9) ≈ 78% of its cell.

## Non-standard PNG, 88 bytes

As pointed out by [@anatolyg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25315),
there is some golfing potential by removing the IEND chunk (12 bytes).
Technically, IEND is [required by the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11Critical-chunks).
However, each PNG chunk includes its own size and checksum information.
It is therefore not absolutely necessary to have an end-marker.
And indeed, all browsers I tested can display the image without issue.

Unfortunately (or fortunately), this non-standard image is rejected by imgur,
so I cannot actually upload it. This is the base64 encoding:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAAA
fCAAAAAA6xUnlAAAAK0lEQVR42mM4gB8wHPgPAwf+M0DAf4TYqDwp
4Ydp0qg8ofBDqMXKGpXHDwDDq0qBspApTg==
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAAA
fCAAAAAA6xUnlAAAAK0lEQVR42mM4gB8wHPgPAwf+M0DAf4TYqDwp
4Ydp0qg8ofBDqMXKGpXHDwDDq0qBspApTg==">
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this valid. `PNG` is not a programming language.

Comment: Thank you MD XF.
@DJMcMayhem Neither is HTML. But considering the small size of the image, I submitted it as an interesting outside-the-box entry.

Comment: But with HTML, you still have to actually write valid HTML to generate the correct output. This is simply taking the correct output, compressing it, and dumping that into an answer.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Fair enough. However, both formats simply describe a static document,
according to their respective standards.
Neither actually constructs the image. Instead,
you have to open them with a browser which then interprets
and displays them. This step, i.e. the
actual "running" of the program, is identical for both formats.
It seems somewhat arbitrary to allow one but not the other.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem [Answers in non-programming-languages are technically allowed by consensus.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/8478) Especially, [for fixed-output challenges.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3639/8478)

Comment: Also, welcome to PPCG, @Meyer! :)

Comment: @Martin Ender Thank you :)

Comment: I definitely think this is a valid submission

Comment: You can remove a few bytes at the end of the file and still have the image. Might depend on a viewer though; I imagine most viewers don't require e.g. the end-chunk to be present.

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks for this suggestion. I have expanded the answer.

Answer (score 12):

### R (<s>130</s> <s>119</s> 113 bytes)

```
plot(c(2,4,6,4,6),c(2,2,2,6,4),an=F,ax=F,xli=(l=c(1,7)),yli=l,xaxs="i",yaxs="i",pch=16,cex=19);grid(3,lt=1);box()
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `axes=F` to replace `xaxt="n",yaxt="n"`. If you double all coordinate values, you save 4 net bytes (but can't use the `1:3,2:3` trick).

Comment: @user2390246: thx for the suggestions. I didn't find much time to golf this out. I'm sure there are more possible improvements. I had to add `;box()` as `axes=F` also removes the frame. Also, as `axes` is a `plot` parameter and not passed on to `par` through `...` as `xaxt`/`yaxt`, it doesn't even need to be spelled out completely.

Comment: You can shave off 7 bytes by (1) replacing `c(1,7)` with a variable (`l=c(1,7)`); (2) replacing `ann` with `an`; (3) replacing `[xy]li` with `[xy]li`; and (4) removing the second, redundant argument to `grid`: `grid(3,lt=1)`. In fact, I’ve taken the liberty of editing this in (under review).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Seems relevant: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/suggested-edits-reject-golfing

Comment: @Matt Hm. Seems that this makes sense if it applies fundamentally different optimisations, rather than just implementing straightforward improvements. Fair enough.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Could always bring it up in Meta if you feel there is a distinction. _I_ would give the OP a chance though first. He likely hasn't seen your comment.

Comment: Matt was right: I was offline for a week. @KonradRudolph: Thx for the great suggestions. However, I saved only 6bytes this way. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2.7, <s>214</s> <s>311</s> 309 bytes

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
f,x=subplots()
j=(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(1,2),(2,1)
for i in j:x.add_artist(Circle((i),.4,color='k'))     
x.tick_params(labelbottom='off',labelleft='off')
for o in x.spines.values():o.set_edgecolor('gray')
for s in 'xy':exec"x.set_"+s+"ticks((.5,1.5,2.5));"+s+"lim(-.5,2.5);"
grid()
```

This is my first attempt here at code golf, so I'm sure this can be improved upon. I would have liked to not established the limits, but it appears that matplotlib can't detect that I plotted circles where I did. Without setting xlim() and ylim() it only shows the bottom two circles.

Output:

[image: Edit]

Edit:Fixed the color of the borders and removed the tick numbers. I must say matplotlib is very densely worded, and not too friendly with changing axis colors.

Shaved off 3 bytes thanks to @DJMcMayhem

Edit:Took off two bytes by setting my ticks as a tuple inside of set_ticks functions.

Comment: Sorry, the numbers on the graph are not allowed. Also, is the border gray?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a nice first answer. :)

Comment: Some minor golfs I see: 1) You can join lines 5 and 6 to remove one space and a newline (-2 bytes) 2) if the order of set xy_ticks and xy_lim doesn't matter, you could do something like `for s in'xy':exec"x.set_"+s+"ticks(a);"+s+"lim(-.5,2.5);"`. (I haven't tested that though, so I'm not positive)

Answer (score 9):

## Bash + ImageMagick, <s>233</s> 226 characters

```bash
convert xc: +antialias -resize 31 -draw "stroke gray fill none ${r=rectangle} 0,0 10,30$r 20,0 30,30$r 0,0 30,10$r 0,20 30,30stroke #000 fill #000 ${c=circle} 15,5 15,8$c 25,15 25,18$c 5,25 5,28$c 15,25 15,28$c 25,25 25,28" x:
```

Sample output:

[image: Glider drawn with Bash and ImageMagick]

#### Bash + ImageMagick, 215 characters

```bash
convert xc: -resize 31 -draw "stroke gray fill none ${r=rectangle} 0,0 10,30$r 20,0 30,30$r 0,0 30,10$r 0,20 30,30stroke #000 fill #000 ${c=circle} 15,5 15,8$c 25,15 25,18$c 5,25 5,28$c 15,25 15,28$c 25,25 25,28" x:
```

The question owner not answered yet the [anti-aliasing question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123797/display-the-hacker-logo/124152#comment304123_123797) and some other solutions also have additional gray shades added by the anti-aliasing, so for now this shorter one looks also acceptable.

Sample output:

[image: Glider drawn with Bash and ImageMagick - with anti-aliasing]

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, <strike>144</strike> <strike>166</strike> <strike>164</strike> <strike>148</strike> 144 bytes

```
require'ruby2d'
set background:'grey'
c=482;g=2,13,24;d=0
g.map{|y|g.map{|x|Square.new(x,y,9);Square.new(x+2,y+2,5,"black")if c[d]>0;d+=1}}
show
```

Output:

[image: output]

Edit: Now has grey gridlines.

Comment: I can see a few golfing opportunities here. For starters, `d=d+1` has a shorter form (`d+=1`) and `==1` here is equivalent to `>0`. Also consider what happens when you set c to a Fixnum instead of an array :-)

Comment: @RJHunter I missed some low hanging fruit! And I thought about stuff like creating a bitfield with c, but couldn't come up with a way that's actually shorter in implementation.

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, Ruby actually has some bitfield support built in! You can access an integer with `[]` as if it were an array of bits (read-only, but that's OK here).

Comment: @RJHunter thanks! All I had to do was change c to the appropriate number. Reduced it quite a bit.

Comment: You can change `g=[2,13,24]` to `g=2,13,24` and replace `each` with `map`.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan! Haha, all these things I'd never do in real Ruby code.

Answer (score 7):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>127</s> 124 bytes

Removed 3 bytes thanks to Luis. `grid` is sufficient (instead of `grid on`).

```matlab
spy([0,1,0;0,0,1;1,1,1],'.k',300),set(gca,'XTick',.5:4,'XTickLabel','','YTick',.5:4,'YTickLabel',''),axis(.5+[0,3,0,3]),grid
```

Outputs (after saving):

Note that the output shows grey grid lines in the plot window. They turn black when saving it (for some reason).

[image]

Well, that was long and messy! Had to go through **a lot** of modifications to make this adhere to the specs.

Explanation and hopefully some golfing coming up...

Comment: That doesn't look very squary, but since the OP did an answer with a similar output I guess it's fine..

Comment: I think the height/width ratio is platform dependent. Add `'square'` to make it square on all platforms. `spy([0,1,0;0,0,1;1,1,1],'.k',80),set(gca,'XTick',.5:4,'XTickLabel','','YTick',.5:4,'YTickLabel',''),axis(.5+[0,3,0,3],'square'),grid on`.

Answer (score 7):

## Tikz, <s>193</s> <s>175</s> 170 bytes

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\def\a{)rectangle(}\def~{)circle(1)(}\draw(4,6\a2,0)(0,\a6,6)(0,2\a6,4);\fill(1,1~3,1~5,1~5,3~3,5~,)}\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: @MDXF It cuts close but since these are perfect circles and squares they make up π/4 of the square which is just about 79% of the square.

Comment: Damn, looked at the challenge and had the exact same idea ;)

Answer (score 7):

## Processing, <strike>212</strike> 198 bytes

```
background(-1);noFill();stroke(99);rect(0,0,99,99);rect(0,33,99,33);rect(33,0,33,99);fill(0);int f=25;ellipse(15,83,f,f);ellipse(50,83,f,f);ellipse(83,83,f,f);ellipse(83,50,f,f);ellipse(50,15,f,f);
```

Basically, we are using simple Processing to draw a white Background, then setting the transparency of the rectangles used for the grid and drawing their strokes in gray. We continue by defining the rectangle, setting the fill value again to fill the circles black and defining fives circles.

Voilà!

[image]

You could add

```
strokeWidth(2);
```

or more to see the color of the strokes better.

(That's my first Code-Golf, I hope I did everything right.)

EDIT: Thanks to Kritixi Lithos! Removed the newlines, changed to int f=25 and used -1 in background(float)

Comment: Great first golf, and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: You can save some bytes by removing the newlines, changing the `float f=25;` to `int f=25;` and by using `background(-1)` instead of `background(255);`

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>74</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```
4:6B&f,.5+w]'k.'5Y08W5$XG7lZG1$3ZG1tZG4:"@th1Kh'k'3$XG1Mbw3$XG
```

Try it at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=4%3A6B%26f%2C.5%2Bw%5D%27k.%275Y08W5%24XG7lZG1%243ZG1tZG4%3A%22%40th1Kh%27k%273%24XG1Mbw3%24XG&inputs=&version=20.0.0) (It takes a few seconds.)

Output from the online interpreter:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## SmileBASIC, 125 bytes

```
GCLS-1GCOLOR #GRAY
GBOX.,8,30,38GBOX 10,8,20,38GBOX.,18,30,28G.,1G 1,2G-1,3G.,3G 1,3DEF G X,Y
GPUTCHR X*10+12,Y*10,58081,.END
```

58081 (U+E2E1, which is in the "Private Use Area" block) is the character code for a circle symbol. Putting it in a string would work too, but since it is encoded as 3 bytes in UTF-8, it would be the same length (and not show up correctly here).

[image: markdown is awful]

Comment: It's always refreshing to see [tag:basic] answers!

Answer (score 4):

### Processing, 134 bytes

Inspired by @Zep, here's my Processing one-liner (and also my first code golf):

```
stroke(127);for(int i=0;i<9;i++){int x=i%3*30;int y=i/3*30;fill(255);rect(x+5,y+5,30,30);if(i==1||i>4){fill(0);ellipse(x+20,y+20,23,23);}};
```

Thanks for @Kritixi Lithos for his brilliant tips on shaving a few bytes off!

[image: glider in Processing]

Comment: Please include a [Language and Score line](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/consensus-for-formatting-of-language-and-score-line).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and nice first answer! As stated by Theraot, all submissions are required to have a header that contains the language and the bytecount. Also, you can golf some bytes by declaring all the variables in the for-loop, like `for(int i=0,x,y;...` so that you can drop the `int` in the body of the loop. Additionally, `fill(255);` can become just `fill(-1);`

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think you can drop the `+20` while setting the values of `x` and `y`, so that you can change the `rect` to `rect(x+5,y+5,30,30);` and the `ellipse` to `ellipse(x+20,y+20,23,23);` and save two bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## LaTeX + Tikz, 155 bytes

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\draw(0,0)grid(3,3);\foreach\x/\y in{0/0,1/0,2/0,2/1,1/2}\fill(\x+.5,\y+.5)circle(.5);}\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Is that `1/0` doing division?

Comment: Sorry, but no, it is a simple separator in the pairs of `x` and `y` coordinates.

Comment: You should be able to save a few bytes by scaling everything up by 2, so that your `.5`'s become just `1`.

Comment: @Chris The grid builtin produces unit-length cells by default, and it takes about 8 bytes more (adding `[step=2]`) to produce a larger grid. Simplifying the coordinates for the circles drawing would not save enough bytes. (You get 157 bytes if you do it)

Comment: @TonioElGringo Ah, true. Teaches me to comment without testing it first ;)

Comment: @TonioElGringo Chris seems to be right after all. I did a plain TeX solution that is basically yours without looking at your solution. ("Great minds think alike.") Anyways: Scaling up by 2 will save you a couple of bytes since you can leave out all the `1`s in co-ordinate entries: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\draw[step=2](0,0)grid(6,6);\foreach\x/\y in{/,3/,5/,5/3,3/5}\fill(\x,\y)circle();}\end{document}` will leave you with 151 bytes. Further improvements: See [my solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205528/95500).

Comment: @TonioElGringo Here's your solution down to 143 bytes with some generic improvements:
`\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz\filldraw[step=2](0,0)grid(6,6)\foreach~/\1in{/,3/,5/,5/3,3/5}{(~,\1)circle()};\end~`. PLUS: You can save more if you don't use the `\foreach`-loop. This will be only 133 bytes: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz{\def~{)circle()(}\filldraw[step=2](0,0)grid(6,6)(,~3,~5,~3,5~5,3~,)}\end~`. Note that this is basically my answer but in LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

## Desmos, 90 characters/bytes

Nobody saw that one coming.

```
(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2<=1
(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2<=1
(x-5)^2+(y-1)^2<=1
(x-5)^2+(y-3)^2<=1
(x-3)^2+(y-5)^2<=1
```

[Graph link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lxzizsxfcp)

Thanks pydude for reminding me about inequalities!

If needed, I can crop the exported Desmos PNG to remove the axis/unneeded graph space

[image: Desmos exported PNG]

[image: Desmos graph]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can fill in the region using an inequality. It will take some more equations to get to work, though.

Comment: @pydude I made the circles inequalities. Thanks.

Comment: A lot of bytes can be saved by rearranging and combining the equations: [Graph link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3b4roejzri)

Comment: [38 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0taq4cozan)

Comment: @AsoneTuhid my gosh you madlad. I'll edit when I get the chance.

Comment: i like this, but i dont think its valid. either youre outputting only the circles, which fails to include the grid, or you're including the whole grid with the numbers, which fails the "Nothing else." requirement. if you're allowed to zoom into a specific part of the grid and only count that part, that seems hard to score...

Answer (score 3):

## R 313 236 bytes

```
l=c(1,7)
bmp('r',400,400)
plot(x=c(4,6,2,4,6),c(6,4,2,2,2),cex=14,pch=19,xlim=l,ylim=l,xlab='',ylab='',xaxs='i',yaxs='i',axes=F)
a=function(s,...){axis(s,labels=F,tck=1, col="gray",lwd=9,...)}
a(1,xaxp=c(l,3))
a(2,yaxp=c(l,3))
dev.off()
```

Revised Code, based mostly on comments from @user2390246 saved 77 bytes.  Much appreciate the help.

Also, want to add a call-out to the shorter R solution by @mschilli. It shows an elegant way of addressing the problem of the R graphical defaults.

## Output

Goes to a file names "r". Omitting and extension saved me four bytes. But then I had to edit the file extension back to "bmp" to get it to upload. So maybe I should not get credit for those four bytes.

[image: The Hacker Logo]

## Commentary

I thought to myself, "That graphic's nothing but a simple graph with five dots. Should be a simple matter to implement in a language with robust data graphics capabilities. Let's try it in R."  But then I had to spend on the order of 80% of the bytes just working around R's graphic defaults.

Kinda the wrong tool for the job....

I could not find a less verbose way of guaranteeing the size and aspect ratio of the graphic than by calling the bmp constructor and then dev.off(). The combination accounts for 25 bytes.  If your R session is set up right, you might get a graphic that looks more or less correct without spending those bytes, but it's not reliable or consistent.

Comment: A few suggestions: don't define your data frame `b` at all, just put the two vectors unnamed directly into the `plot` function. Use `c(l,3)` for `xaxp` and `yaxp`. You can just use `F` for false, no need to define it. And define a new function `a(x,...)` that calls `axis(x)` but has default values for labels, tck, etc, so that you don't need to specify them all twice.

Comment: You can also use `axes=F` rather than `xaxt='n',yaxt='n'`. And you forgot to use `.5` when defining `l` though you did use that trick later.

Comment: Actually, what if you doubled all coordinate values to get rid of those pesky `.5`s altogether?

Comment: If you're already gonna take off the `.bmp` file extension, you might as well just name the file `r`.

Comment: @user2390246 -- Many thanks for the suggestions.  Cumulatively saved on the order of 70 bytes.  This  was my first effort at golfing in R, and you spotted a lot of tyro's errors I probably should have seen.  Next time I'll know better.

Comment: I don’t think you need the code to save this to a file, other answers don’t have it either.

Comment: I agree @Konrad Rudolf that the added code to save to a file is not strictly necessary, but for now I'll leave it in. mschilli has an elegant solution without the extra code (which is shorter than this one).  But I could not generate output that I was satisfied with without it.  The lwd = 9 is also mostly here for aesthetic purposes, and so could also be removed.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 333 bytes

```c#
using System.Drawing;_=>{var b=new Bitmap(31,31);var g=Graphics.FromImage(b);g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White,0,0,31,31);for(int x=0,y;x<3;++x)for(y=0;y<3;++y){g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray,x*10,y*10,10,10);if(x==1&y<1|x>1&y==1|y>1)g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black,x*10+1,y*10+1,8,8);}b.Save("t.png");System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("t.png");};
```

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
using System.Drawing;
Action<int> a = _ =>
{
    var b = new Bitmap(31, 31);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 31, 31);

    for (int x = 0, y; x < 3; ++x)
        for (y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
            if (x == 1 & y < 1 | x > 1 & y == 1 | y > 1)
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, x * 10 + 1, y * 10 + 1, 8, 8);
        }

    b.Save("t.png");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("t.png");
};
```

Idea is simple we create a graphics object from the image and use that to make the image all white. Then loop over each square of the image drawing the bounding rectangle. If it is one of the locations for a dot we draw that too. Lastly we save the image to file and let windows decide how to open it, in my case it opens with Windows Photo Viewer.

Using a `Process` to show the image and saving to file is a lot shorter than creating a windows forms or WPF app because of all the different classes and extra fluff needed to create them.

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I don't think you have to use Process.Start, for example Titus answer just outputs image, doesn't open it

Comment: @JeremyThompson the rules state you must display the image

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 221+2 bytes

```php
<?imagefill($i=imagecreatetruecolor(31,31),0,0,~0);function q($i,$x,$y,$f){imagerectangle($i,$x*=10,$y*=10,$x+10,$y+10,5e6);$f?:imagefilledellipse($i,$x+5,$y+5,8,8,0);}for($p=16;$p--;)q($i,$p&3,$p>>2,53>>$p&1);imagepng($i);
```

Save to file; call in browser. Should your browser display gibberish,
insert `header("Content-Type:image-png");` before `imagepng($i);`.

[image: output] The dots aren´t very round; that´s due to the small proportions.

**breakdown**

```php
function q($i,$x,$y,$f){        # function to draw quadrant:
    imagerectangle($i,$x*=10,$y*=10,$x+10,$y+10,5e6);   # draw lines in 0x4c4b40
    $f?:imagefilledellipse($i,$x+5,$y+5,8,8,0);         # if bit not set, draw dot
}

imagefill($i=
    imagecreatetruecolor(31,31) # create image
    ,0,0,~0);                   # fill with 0xffffff (white)
for($p=16;$p--;)q($i,           # loop through positions, call function
    $p&3,                           # $x=lower two bits
    $p>>2,                          # $y=upper two bits
    53>>$p&1                        # $f=one bit from %0000 0000 0011 0101
);                                      # (reversed inverted bit mask for dots)
imagepng($i);                   # output image
```

I think that `0x4c4b40` qualifies as approximated gray. If not, add four bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, <s>218</s> <s>140</s> 137 bytes

Note: this byte count is a bit inflated. The program only uses 85 tokens, but that's saved in 137 bytes. Also, if you're using a non-color calculator, you could save another 4 tokens because you don't have to specify the color (which is blue by default), but I don't know if their screens are large enough for this challenge because I don't own one.

prgmHACKER (138 bytes, 86 tokens):

```
{0,1,2,1,2}→L1
{0,0,0,2,1}→L2
.3→R
For(I,0,5
L₁(I)+.5→A
L₂(I)+.5→B
For(N,0,R,dX
√(R²-N²
Line(A+N,B-Ans,A+N,B+Ans,BLACK
Line(A-N,B-Ans,A-N,B+Ans,BLACK
End
End
```

For proper display, this program requires that Xmin = Ymin = 0, Xmax = Ymax = 3, Xscl = Yscl = 1. dX also needs to be properly set, but the calculator does that for you when you set any other window variable. I couldn't see how much space these variables used in RAM.

Furthermore, the format settings should be { RectGC, CoordOff, GridLine, GridColor:MEDGRAY, Axes:OFF, ExprOff, BorderColor:1, Background:OFF } but these are toggled values and don't consume any extra space depending on the setting.

Comment: To golf down the list, you could express these as `{0,1,2,1,2}` and `{0,0,0,2,1}` then add `0.5` to each item.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't change the amount of RAM used by the lists. However, you gave me the idea to get rid of the lists in RAM and define them when the program runs, saving 78 bytes in RAM.

Comment: Order in the golf people!
Change the `L1` and `L2` to `L₁` and `L₂`, since you already use them. 
I think you can remove `}`, and `L₁(I)+.5→A`=>`.5+L₁(I` and `L₂(I)+.5→B` => `.5+L₂(I→B`.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>119</s> <s>114</s> 111 bytes

(Thans to [@JayCe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80010) for saving me 3 bytes)

Not shorter than the [other R solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123925/6741), but a completely different approach:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,9,2:8),3,,T))
par(mar=0*1:4)
for(i in 1:9){frame();if(i>4)points(.5,.5,,19,cex=29);box(fg=8)}
```

Uses a layout in which the 4 first plots are the empty cells, and the 5 others the ones with dots in them.

[image: Glider]

Comment: Can me made shorter than the other solution using positional arguments: [here](https://tio.run/##DclBCsIwEAXQfU/R5XwZxNQKTUo8hReIpZEB25QxQkQ8eyy83dNan@GT3pmWkFUKTWTYcucG8Jn5BjRb0D3Vnw7G9WhiUpJW1tY4i2/UsMyEUSLJtceWZM0vOl54x8byNBffWYz3VCg@/IBfrX8)

Comment: @JayCe indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA,  180 bytes

An anonymous VBE Immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the default worksheet object (`Sheet1`).

```vb
Cells.RowHeight=48:Cells.Interior.Color=-1:[B2:D4].Borders.Color=7434613:For Each s In[{21,32,13,23,33}]:Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(9,48*(s\10)+4,Mid(s,2)*48+4,40,40).ShapeStyle=8:Next
```

**Commented Version**

```vb
Cells.RowHeight=48                      ''  Make the Cells square
Cells.Interior.Color=-1                 ''  Remove the default grid
[B2:D4].Borders.Color=7434613           ''  Create the 3x3 gray grid at range `B2:D4`
For Each s In [{21,32,13,23,33}]        ''  Assign and iterate over a list of where
                                        ''  to place the dots; This list is a range that 
                                        ''  is coerced into a numeric array
        
    Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(         _   ''  Add a shape to the Sheet1 object
                9,                  _   ''  An Oval (msoShapeOval)
                48*(s\10)+4,        _   ''  At the calculated value from the left
                Mid(s,2)*48+4,      _   ''  At the calculated value from the top
                40,                 _   ''  that is 40 units wide
                40                  _   ''  and is 40 units tall
                ).ShapeStyle=8          ''  and is black filled with a black outline

Next                                    ''  repeat to end of list
```

**Output**

[image: Hacker Logo]

-6 bytes for using `[{21,32,13,23,33}]` over  `Split("21 32 13 23 33")`

-2 bytes for using `Mid(s,2)` over `Right(s,1)`

-3 bytes for using `(s\10)` over `Left(s,1)`

Answer (score 2):

## gnuplot, <s>158</s> 156 bytes

```
se si ra-1
se xti 2
se yti 2
se st l 9 lc"gray"lt 1
se gr xt ls 9 yt ls 9
se bor ls 9
uns k
se form""
p'-'w cir fc"black"fs s
3 5 1
5 3 1
1 1 1
3 1 1
5 1 1
```

Because the radii are the same, I tried the following:

```
[... first eight lines same as above ...]
p'-'u 1:2:(1) w cir fc"black"fs s
3 5
5 3
1 1
3 1
5 1
```

But that lead to the same byte count.

Ungolfed with comments:

```
set size ratio -1                                     # make it a square.
set xtics 2                                           # vertical lines every 2 units
set ytics 2                                           # horizontal lines every 2 units
set style line 9 linecolor rgb "gray" linetype 1      # define line type 9 as solid gray
set grid xtics linestyle 9 ytics linestyle 9          # make internal lines of type 9
set border linestyle 9                                # make outside lines of type 9
unset key                                             # no legend please
set format ""                                         # no numbers next to axes please
plot '-' with circle fillcolor rgb "black" fill solid # plot black circles
3 5 1                                                 # at these locations
5 3 1
1 1 1
3 1 1
5 1 1
end
```

[image]

Comment: Are the circles <= 80% of the grid-boxes?

Comment: Maybe by area, /4 ≈ 78%

Comment: Yes, they cover pi/4, which is around 78%. I could make them slightly smaller and look better, but that would cost byte.

Comment: ... would cost *one* byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave <s>107</s> <s>94</s> 103 bytes

```
scatter([1:3,3,2],[1,1,1:3],1e5,zeros(5,3),'.');axis off;a=[1,7]/2;for i=.5:3.5;line(a,i);line(i,a);end
```

or

```
plot([1:3,3,2],[1,1,1:3],'k.','markersize',250);axis off;a=[1,7]/2;for i=.5:3.5;line(a,i);line(i,a);end
```

both solutions are 103 bytes.

[image]

Comment: I believe the dots have to be black

Comment: ah, interesting, matlab interprets a scalar as a point, as opposed to broadcasting it. so instead of `line([x1,x2],y)` you have to do `line([x1,x2],[y,y])`

Answer (score 2):

### Apple Swift (iOS - CoreGraphics/QuartzCore) - 832 Bytes

I drew the shape entirely using Quartz for an Apple iOS device. Unfortunatly this isn't a particularly size mindful language so the result is quite large, but this is as small as I can get it.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width:60,height:60));let c=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!;UIColor.lightGray.setStroke();c.addRect(CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:60,height:60));c.move(to: CGPoint(x:20,y:0));c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:20,y:60));c.move(to: CGPoint(x:40,y:0));c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:40,y:60));c.move(to: CGPoint(x:0,y:20));c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:60,y:20));c.move(to: CGPoint(x:0,y:40));c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:60, y:40));c.strokePath();UIColor.black.setFill();c.addEllipse(in:CGRect(x:22,y:2,width:16,height:16));c.addEllipse(in:CGRect(x:42,y:22,width:16,height:16));c.addEllipse(in:CGRect(x:2,y:42,width:16,height:16));c.addEllipse(in:CGRect(x:22,y:42,width:16,height:16));c.addEllipse(in:CGRect(x:42,y:42,width:16,height:16));c.fillPath();let i=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();sub.addSubview(UIImageView(image:i))
```

A more readable version for anyone that is interested:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    
    UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
    c.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
    c.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 0))
    c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 60))
    c.move(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 0))
    c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 60))
    c.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20))
    c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 60, y: 20))
    c.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 40))
    c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 60, y: 40))
    c.strokePath()
    
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    c.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 22, y: 2, width: 16, height: 16))
    c.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 42, y: 22, width: 16, height: 16))
    c.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 2, y: 42, width: 16, height: 16))
    c.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 22, y: 42, width: 16, height: 16))
    c.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 42, y: 42, width: 16, height: 16))
    c.fillPath()
    
    let i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    sub.addSubview(UIImageView(image: i))
```

Here is the output produced in the iOS Simulator:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby with Shoes, 118 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app{9.times{|i|
stroke gray
fill white
rect x=i%3*w=10,y=i/3*w,w,w
stroke fill black
oval x+2,y+2,7if 482[i]>0}}
```

Bit checking borrowed from [RJHunter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14775/rjhunter)'s [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123797/display-the-hacker-logo#comment304648_123827) made on [Mark Thomas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3743/mark-thomas)'s [Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123827).

Sample output:

[image: Glider drawn with Ruby with Shoes]

Answer (score 2):

## SVG + HTML, <s>146</s> <s>138</s> <s>135</s> 133 bytes

```html
<svg>
<path fill=none stroke=#ccc d=m.5.5h30v30h-30zh10v30h10v-30zv10h30v10h-30 />
<path d=m11,1h9v9m1,1h9v9m-29,1h9v9m1-9h9v9m1-9h9v9>
```

Thanks to the lenient HTML parser, the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` declaration
can be omitted, as well as attribute quotes and the closing tag.
This version addresses some issues of other HTML solutions:

- A "dot" is guaranteed to fill at least 40% of its cell (§1)
- It does not use external graphics, e.g. font glyphs (§2, §6)
- The grid is perfectly square (§5)

**Edit** Shaved off 8 bytes by exploiting the fact that subpaths do not
need to be closed in order to be [filled](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties).

**Edit** According to the [svg grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF),
it is not necessary to separate non-digits with a comma (`.5,.5`).
I also abandoned the explicit fill, so that I can change the draw direction
of one line from negative to positive, saving a dash. And lastly,
I adjusted the count to not include a trailing newline, sorry for this rookie mistake.

**Edit** Learning from [another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26752/70228) on codegolf,
I have replaced the final `9 />` with `9>`. This works fine in all tested browsers.

Answer (score 2):

## [OpenTuring](https://github.com/Open-Turing-Project/OpenTuring), <s>203</s> 189 bytes

This is a language I hated in high school, but it has graphics, so...

```
for i:0..2
for j:0..2
Draw.Box(i*30,j*30,(i+1)*30,(j+1)*30,28)
if j=0 then
Draw.FillOval(i*30+15,15,12,12,7)
end if
end for
end for
Draw.FillOval(45,75,12,12,7)
Draw.FillOval(75,45,12,12,7)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @MDXF, oh sorry, I just remembered about the screenshot, I'll add it now

Comment: No problem; thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 + PyGame, 238 Bytes

```
from pygame import*
d=display
s=d.set_mode([55]*2)
s.fill([255]*3)
f=lambda*a:draw.line(s,[128]*3,*a)
for x in[0,18,36,54]:
 f((x,0),(x,55));f((0,x),(55,x))
for x,y in zip([3,5,1,3,5],[1,3,5,5,5]):draw.circle(s,[0]*3,(x*9,y*9),7)
d.flip()
```

The seemingly arbitrary constants are from me trying to make the image as large as possible without sacrificing bytes.

## With non-printing characters, 229 Bytes

```
from pygame import*
d=display
s=d.set_mode([55]*2)
s.fill([255]*3)
f=lambda*a:draw.line(s,[128]*3,*a)
for x in b'\0␒$6':
 f((x,0),(x,55));f((0,x),(55,x))
for x,y in zip(b'␃␅␁␃␅',b'␁␃␅␅␅'):draw.circle(s,[0]*3,(x*9,y*9),7)
d.flip()
```

I replaced the lists with byte literals, which saves a bunch of characters, but the non-printing characters can't be displayed properly here. I substituted the non-printing characters with their graphical equivalents U+2400-U+2421 for display purposes.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## Postscript (72 bytes)

```
00000000: 924e 337b 924e 337b 3088 0034 2034 9281  .N3{.N3{0..4 4..
00000010: 3420 3092 ad7d 9283 924d 3020 3492 ad7d  4 0..}...M0 4..}
00000020: 9283 924d 337b 3188 0132 2032 9280 3420  ...M3{1..2 2..4
00000030: 3092 ad7d 9283 327b 88fc 3492 ad31 8801  0..}..2{..4..1..
00000040: 3220 3292 807d 9283                      2 2..}..
```

Text version:

```
gsave 3{gsave 3{0 0 4 4 rectstroke 4 0 translate}repeat grestore 0 4 translate}repeat grestore 3{1 1 2 2 rectfill 4 0 translate}repeat 2{-4 4 translate 1 1 2 2 rectfill}repeat
```

More readable text version:

```
/R {1 1 2 2 rectfill}def
gsave
3 {gsave 3 {0 0 4 4 rectstroke 4 0 translate} repeat grestore 0 4 translate} repeat
grestore
3 {R 4 0 translate} repeat
2 {-4 4 translate R} repeat
```

Comment: These don't render correctly for me. (And the last one looks rather different to the first two).

Comment: it should be correct now

Comment: Yes, thanks! (I guess your interpretation for the gridline colors is that black is a shade of gray :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 310 bytes

```
00 C0 A9 00 A8 85 FC A2 E0 86 FD A2 20 91 FC C8 D0 FB E6 FD CA D0 F6 A2 CC 86
FD A2 18 A0 27 C0 09 F0 20 C0 06 F0 1C C0 03 F0 18 C0 00 F0 14 E0 18 F0 10 E0
15 F0 0C E0 12 F0 08 E0 0F F0 04 A9 01 D0 02 A9 C1 91 FC 88 10 D5 A5 FC 69 27
85 FC A5 FD 69 00 85 FD CA 10 C4 A9 FF A2 0F 9D 60 E1 9D A0 E2 9D 38 E5 9D 78
E6 9D C8 E8 9D 08 EA 9D E0 E8 9D 20 EA 9D F8 E8 9D 38 EA CA 10 DF A9 40 85 FC
A9 E1 85 FD A2 20 A0 00 A9 18 91 FC C8 98 29 07 D0 F6 98 69 10 A8 CA F0 13 8A
29 03 D0 EA A5 FC 69 40 85 FC A5 FD 69 01 85 FD D0 DA A9 18 A2 02 9D 05 E0 9D
1D E0 9D 35 E0 9D 4D E0 9D 40 EB 9D 58 EB 9D 70 EB 9D 88 EB CA 10 E5 A9 0B 85
FC A9 E0 85 FD A2 20 A0 00 A9 FF 91 FC C8 98 29 01 D0 F6 98 69 06 A8 CA F0 13
8A 29 07 D0 EA A5 FC 69 C0 85 FC A5 FD 69 03 85 FD D0 DA A9 1F A2 01 9D 03 E0
9D C3 E3 9D 83 E7 9D 43 EB 49 E7 9D 4B E0 9D 0B E4 9D CB E7 9D 8B EB 49 E7 CA
10 E1 A9 94 8D 00 DD A9 3B 8D 11 D0 A9 3D 8D 18 D0 A9 01 8D 20 D0 D0 FE
```

I expected this to be possible in fewer bytes, but didn't find a way for quite a while, so posting it anyways now :)

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"hacker.prg":"data:;base64,AMCpAKiF/KLghv2iIJH8yND75v3K0PaizIb9ohigJ8AJ8CDABvAcwAPwGMAA8BTgGPAQ4BXwDOAS8AjgD/AEqQHQAqnBkfyIENWl/Gknhfyl/WkAhf3KEMSp/6IPnWDhnaDinTjlnXjmncjonQjqneDonSDqnfjonTjqyhDfqUCF/Knhhf2iIKAAqRiR/MiYKQfQ9phpEKjK8BOKKQPQ6qX8aUCF/KX9aQGF/dDaqRiiAp0F4J0d4J014J1N4J1A651Y651w652I68oQ5akLhfyp4IX9oiCgAKn/kfzImCkB0PaYaQaoyvATiikH0Oql/GnAhfyl/WkDhf3Q2qkfogGdA+Cdw+Odg+edQ+tJ551L4J0L5J3L552L60nnyhDhqZSNAN2pO40R0Kk9jRjQqQGNINDQ/g=="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"hacker.prg"%7D%7D)**, Usage: `sys49152`

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Explanation:** (commented vice disassembly listing)

```
         00 C0       .WORD $C000

         ; clear 8kiB monochrome bitmap at $E000:
         ;---------------------------------------
.C:c000  A9 00       LDA #$00
.C:c002  A8          TAY
.C:c003  85 FC       STA $FC
.C:c005  A2 E0       LDX #$E0
.C:c007  86 FD       STX $FD
.C:c009  A2 20       LDX #$20       ; 16 pages to clear
.C:c00b   .cl_loop:
.C:c00b  91 FC       STA ($FC),Y
.C:c00d  C8          INY
.C:c00e  D0 FB       BNE .cl_loop
.C:c010  E6 FD       INC $FD
.C:c012  CA          DEX
.C:c013  D0 F6       BNE .cl_loop

     ; set colors for each 8x8 pixel block:
         ; ------------------------------------
.C:c015  A2 CC       LDX #$CC       ; start address of bitmap colors
.C:c017  86 FD       STX $FD        ; ($CC00) in zeropage pointer
.C:c019  A2 18       LDX #$18       ; 25 rows
.C:c01b   .sc_loop1:
.C:c01b  A0 27       LDY #$27       ; 40 columns (counts down to 0)
.C:c01d   .sc_loop2:
.C:c01d  C0 09       CPY #$09       ; for every third column ...
.C:c01f  F0 20       BEQ .sc_gray
.C:c021  C0 06       CPY #$06
.C:c023  F0 1C       BEQ .sc_gray
.C:c025  C0 03       CPY #$03
.C:c027  F0 18       BEQ .sc_gray
.C:c029  C0 00       CPY #$00
.C:c02b  F0 14       BEQ .sc_gray
.C:c02d  E0 18       CPX #$18       ; ... or every third row ...
.C:c02f  F0 10       BEQ .sc_gray
.C:c031  E0 15       CPX #$15
.C:c033  F0 0C       BEQ .sc_gray
.C:c035  E0 12       CPX #$12
.C:c037  F0 08       BEQ .sc_gray
.C:c039  E0 0F       CPX #$0F
.C:c03b  F0 04       BEQ .sc_gray   ; ... use gray ($C) on white ($1)
.C:c03d  A9 01       LDA #$01       ; else use black ($0) on white ($1)
.C:c03f  D0 02       BNE .sc_store
.C:c041   .sc_gray:
.C:c041  A9 C1       LDA #$C1
.C:c043   .sc_store:
.C:c043  91 FC       STA ($FC),Y    ; store color
.C:c045  88          DEY
.C:c046  10 D5       BPL .sc_loop2
.C:c048  A5 FC       LDA $FC        ; add offset for next row to pointer
.C:c04a  69 27       ADC #$27
.C:c04c  85 FC       STA $FC
.C:c04e  A5 FD       LDA $FD
.C:c050  69 00       ADC #$00
.C:c052  85 FD       STA $FD
.C:c054  CA          DEX
.C:c055  10 C4       BPL .sc_loop1

         ; draw "dots" as solid squares of 16x16
         ; -------------------------------------
.C:c057  A9 FF       LDA #$FF       ; all 8 pixels set
.C:c059  A2 0F       LDX #$0F       ; loop over 2*8 = 16 rows
.C:c05b   .sq_loop:
.C:c05b  9D 60 E1    STA $E160,X    ; store at different offsets
.C:c05e  9D A0 E2    STA $E2A0,X    ; this works because of the strange
.C:c061  9D 38 E5    STA $E538,X    ; VIC-II framebuffer memory layout:
.C:c064  9D 78 E6    STA $E678,X    ;
.C:c067  9D C8 E8    STA $E8C8,X    ; 8 consecutive bytes form a block
.C:c06a  9D 08 EA    STA $EA08,X    ; of 8x8 pixels.
.C:c06d  9D E0 E8    STA $E8E0,X    ; The next 8x8 block is to the right
.C:c070  9D 20 EA    STA $EA20,X    ; of the previous one.
.C:c073  9D F8 E8    STA $E8F8,X    ; after 40 of these blocks, a new row
.C:c076  9D 38 EA    STA $EA38,X    ; starts.
.C:c079  CA          DEX
.C:c07a  10 DF       BPL .sq_loop

         ; draw vertical grid lines:
         ; -------------------------
.C:c07c  A9 40       LDA #$40       ; load vector with
.C:c07e  85 FC       STA $FC        ; start address of the
.C:c080  A9 E1       LDA #$E1       ; first grid line
.C:c082  85 FD       STA $FD
.C:c084  A2 20       LDX #$20       ; 32 line segments
.C:c086   .gv_loop1:
.C:c086  A0 00       LDY #$00       ; start offset at 0
.C:c088   .gv_loop2:
.C:c088  A9 18       LDA #$18       ; bit pattern for 2pixel wide line
.C:c08a  91 FC       STA ($FC),Y    ; store bit pattern in bitmap
.C:c08c  C8          INY
.C:c08d  98          TYA
.C:c08e  29 07       AND #$07       ; every 8 lines ...
.C:c090  D0 F6       BNE .gv_loop2
.C:c092  98          TYA        ; ... add 16 to offset to
.C:c093  69 10       ADC #$10       ; skip 2 columns
.C:c095  A8          TAY
.C:c096  CA          DEX
.C:c097  F0 13       BEQ .gov
.C:c099  8A          TXA
.C:c09a  29 03       AND #$03       ; every 4 line segments ...
.C:c09c  D0 EA       BNE .gv_loop2
.C:c09e   .gh:
.C:c09e  A5 FC       LDA $FC        ; ... add $140 (8 * 25) to vector
.C:c0a0  69 40       ADC #$40       ; to get one "row" down
.C:c0a2  85 FC       STA $FC
.C:c0a4  A5 FD       LDA $FD
.C:c0a6  69 01       ADC #$01
.C:c0a8  85 FD       STA $FD
.C:c0aa  D0 DA       BNE .gv_loop1

         ; draw vertical grid line endings:
         ; --------------------------------
.C:c0ac   .gov:
.C:c0ac  A9 18       LDA #$18
.C:c0ae  A2 02       LDX #$02       ; every ending is 3 pixels high
.C:c0b0   .gov_loop:
.C:c0b0  9D 05 E0    STA $E005,X    ; store at different offsets
.C:c0b3  9D 1D E0    STA $E01D,X    ; in bitmap, see explanation
.C:c0b6  9D 35 E0    STA $E035,X    ; for squares above
.C:c0b9  9D 4D E0    STA $E04D,X
.C:c0bc  9D 40 EB    STA $EB40,X
.C:c0bf  9D 58 EB    STA $EB58,X
.C:c0c2  9D 70 EB    STA $EB70,X
.C:c0c5  9D 88 EB    STA $EB88,X
.C:c0c8  CA          DEX
.C:c0c9  10 E5       BPL .gov_loop

         ; draw horizontal grid lines:
         ; ---------------------------
.C:c0cb  A9 0B       LDA #$0B       ; load vector with
.C:c0cd  85 FC       STA $FC        ; start address of the
.C:c0cf  A9 E0       LDA #$E0       ; first grid line
.C:c0d1  85 FD       STA $FD
.C:c0d3  A2 20       LDX #$20       ; 32 line segments
.C:c0d5   .gh_loop1:
.C:c0d5  A0 00       LDY #$00       ; start offset at 0
.C:c0d7   .gh_loop2:
.C:c0d7  A9 FF       LDA #$FF       ; all bits set for horizontal lines
.C:c0d9  91 FC       STA ($FC),Y    ; store bit pattern in bitmap
.C:c0db  C8          INY
.C:c0dc  98          TYA
.C:c0dd  29 01       AND #$01       ; every other line ...
.C:c0df  D0 F6       BNE .gh_loop2
.C:c0e1  98          TYA
.C:c0e2  69 06       ADC #$06       ; ... add 6 to offset to get to the
.C:c0e4  A8          TAY        ; next block
.C:c0e5  CA          DEX
.C:c0e6  F0 13       BEQ .goh
.C:c0e8  8A          TXA
.C:c0e9  29 07       AND #$07       ; every 8 line segments ...
.C:c0eb  D0 EA       BNE .gh_loop2
.C:c0ed  A5 FC       LDA $FC        ; ... add $3C0 (8 * 75) to vector
.C:c0ef  69 C0       ADC #$C0       ; to get three "rows" down
.C:c0f1  85 FC       STA $FC
.C:c0f3  A5 FD       LDA $FD
.C:c0f5  69 03       ADC #$03
.C:c0f7  85 FD       STA $FD
.C:c0f9  D0 DA       BNE .gh_loop1

         ; draw horizontal grid line endings:
         ; ----------------------------------
.C:c0fb   .goh:
.C:c0fb  A9 1F       LDA #$1F       ; bit pattern for 5 pixel wide line end
.C:c0fd  A2 01       LDX #$01       ; 2 pixels high
.C:c0ff   .goh_loop:
.C:c0ff  9D 03 E0    STA $E003,X    ; store at different offsets ...
.C:c102  9D C3 E3    STA $E3C3,X
.C:c105  9D 83 E7    STA $E783,X
.C:c108  9D 43 EB    STA $EB43,X
.C:c10b  49 E7       EOR #$E7       ; switch to right line end
.C:c10d  9D 4B E0    STA $E04B,X    ; and store ...
.C:c110  9D 0B E4    STA $E40B,X
.C:c113  9D CB E7    STA $E7CB,X
.C:c116  9D 8B EB    STA $EB8B,X
.C:c119  49 E7       EOR #$E7       ; switch back to left line end
.C:c11b  CA          DEX
.C:c11c  10 E1       BPL .goh_loop

         ; setup hardware to show graphics:
         ; --------------------------------
.C:c11e  A9 94       LDA #$94       ; select top bank for VIC-II
.C:c120  8D 00 DD    STA $DD00      ; address space ($C000 - $FFFF)
.C:c123  A9 3B       LDA #$3B       ; activate hires bitmap mode
.C:c125  8D 11 D0    STA $D011
.C:c128  A9 3D       LDA #$3D       ; select $0c00 for start of bitmap
.C:c12a  8D 18 D0    STA $D018      ; colors, $2000 for start of bitmap
.C:c12d  A9 01       LDA #$01       ; set border color to white
.C:c12f  8D 20 D0    STA $D020
.C:c132   .hl_end:
.C:c132  D0 FE       BNE .hl_end    ; --- and never come back (loop)
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++ using SFML, <s>708</s> <s>706</s> 685 bytes

-23 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#define V =RectangleShape({6.f,300.f});r
#define H =RectangleShape({300.f,6.f});r
#define S(a,b).setPosition(a,b);
#define D(c,d)a.setPosition(c,d);w.draw(a);
using namespace sf;int main(){RenderWindow w(VideoMode(300,300),"");RectangleShape r[8];r[0]V[1]V[2]V[3]V[4]H[5]H[6]H[7]H[0]S(-3,0)r[1]S(97,0)r[2]S(197,0)r[3]S(297,0)r[4]S(0,-3)r[5]S(0,97)r[6]S(0,197)r[7]S(0,297)CircleShape a(40);a.setFillColor(Color::Black);while(w.isOpen()){Event e;while(w.pollEvent(e))if(e.type==Event::Closed)w.close();w.clear(Color::White);for(int i=0;i<8;++i){r[i].setFillColor(Color(128,128,128));w.draw(r[i]);}D(110,10)D(210,110)D(210,210)D(110,210)D(10,210)w.display();}}
```

Open a window where you see that :

[image: SFML Displaying the hacker logo]

Window is 300x300, so grid boxes are 100x100, and the dot have a 40 pixel radius, so the number of covered pixels is `40*40*3.14` ( something like 5024 ). So it respects the 40%-80% area filling rule.

If you want to run it by yourself, you should add this line : `w.setFramerateLimit(60)`, to avoid your computer to heat up

Comment: IIRC, you don't need a space between your macros and the definitions in this case. I'll work on extreme macro abuse right now.

Comment: @Zacharý I can for `S` and `D`, but not for `V` and `H`

Comment: Here's what I got, because when I tested that macro-equal-thing on g++ (albeit with a different program) it worked, so you may have to change a few things here and there for it to work in MSVC: https://pastebin.com/0uTHTc4Q

Answer (score 2):

## TikZ + TeX (plain TeX) <s>86</s> 83 bytes

```
\input tikz\def~{)circle()(}\tikz\filldraw[step=2]grid(6,6)(,~3,~5,~5,3~3,5~,);\bye
```

[Try online](https://www.overleaf.com/read/gcxgqhhktqwn)

### Explanation

I recently found out that plain TeX saves you lots of bytes when compared to LaTeX. Started this one from scratch.

- `\input tikz` loads the TikZ-library
- `\def~{)circle()(}` defines the single-character-macro `~` (`~` is the only active character!) as shorthand for some text. This macro does not need any argument to be supplied. Note that the circle has a radius of 1 if we do not supply an argument.
- `\tikz` starts the picture
- `\filldraw` draws the grid and fills the circles at the same time
- `[step=2]` leaves, by default, 2 units of space between gridlines, cf. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45808/tikz-grid-lines)
- `grid(6,6)` produces the 3x3 grid
- `(,~3,~5,~5,3~3,5~` paints the circles by using the `~`-macro and, in the end, opens another co-ordinate with the last use of `~`. Note that, whenever the digit 1 could've been supplied in a co-ordinate entry, I just left it out. This happened three times, with `(1,1)`, `(3,1)`, and `(5,1)`.
- `,)` completes this co-ordinate. It becomes, in total, `(,)` which is equivalent to `(1,1)`, see above, but does not have any effect on the output.
- `;` ends the filldraw command. We could leave it out if we surrounded everything between `\tikz` and `\bye` with curly braces but this would be two bytes more resulting in a grand total of one byte more.
- `\bye` ends the TeX document.

### What about GRAY?

This is a little tricky but I believe that `rgb(x,x,x)` with `0≤x≤255` are 256 shades of gray. Basically, black is the darkest gray available.

### Output

[image: TeX Output]

Answer (score 2):

## Applesoft Basic, <s>405</s> 291 bytes

```basic
0data51,29,73,51,73,73,51,73,29,73
1hgr:hcolor=3:fori=0to123:hplot0,i to123,i:next
2hcolor=0:fori=18to84step22:hplot18,i to84,i:hploti,18toi,84:next
3fori=1to5:reada,b:a=a+.5:b=b+.5:gosub8:next:end
8forr=1to9:hplota,b:forn=0to6.3step.1:y=sin(n)*r:x=cos(n)*r:hplottoa+x,b+y
9next:next:return
```

[image]

`0data...` locates the circles. `1hgr...` draws white background. `2hcolor...` draws grid. `3for..read..` gets data & calls the circle subroutine. (`.5` is added at various points because of quirky Apple II drawing logic). `8for...` to `9..return` draws circles. (circle code adapted from [hoist-point.com](http://www.hoist-point.com/applesoft_basic_tutorial.htm#drawing_circle_section)). Verified at https://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/

- version 1: [405 bytes](https://gist.github.com/roblogic/7b2633a4469b0369f49993b02d542304)
- a crappy version that fits in [a tweet](https://twitter.com/roblogic_/status/1339345355008212993?s=20)!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer in Tcl/Tk 17 lines, 582 Characters:

```
proc box {sz x y} {return [list [expr {$x*$sz+4}] [expr {$y*$sz+4}] [expr {($x+1)*$sz+4}] [expr {($y+1)*$sz+4}]]}
proc oval {sz x y} {return [list [expr {$x*$sz+($sz*0.8)+4}] [expr {$y*$sz+($sz*0.8)+4}] [expr {($x+1)*$sz-($sz*0.8)+4}] [expr {($y+1)*$sz-($sz*0.8)+4}]]}
set SIZE 100
canvas .c -width [expr {$SIZE*3+8}] -height [expr {$SIZE*3+8}]
pack .c
set y 0
foreach row {{0 1 0} {0 0 1} {1 1 1}} {
set x 0
foreach dot $row {
.c create rectangle {*}[box $SIZE $x $y] -fill {} -outline grey -width 1
if {$dot} {
.c create oval {*}[oval $SIZE $x $y] -fill black
}
incr x
}
incr y
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The dots you are using only cover around 28% of the white fill of each cell, the requirement is to cover with the range 40-80%. (It may even cost less bytes to fill ~79% by removing the `*0.8`s)

Comment: Comparing to [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141356/29325), yours is code-bowling!

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/), 391 bytes

```bash
xxd -ps -r<<G|
425a6839314159265359e008ecc700015afa48d2582082482013004000002008010008b000f920484289880d30a069a1919310294a1a50d19a8c4e5394d2689a8b5057b493c759b1374c26136c94fae37ceb40bf7c73fdc3d07e6f95f69d8440f2040209a5281d49e9fbbcb692bc07725bcbcb62a6e106510a635089343060c630bc075b6dacd71ae32b7c6ec64b0b03e0457c912b22f31613c9305e46558c2bd589e9313b2602f6e3aff177245385090e008ecc70
G
bzcat|feh -
```

The hex string in the heredoc is a PNM image of the logo, compressed with BZip2 at level 9. `xxd -ps -r` converts it into binary data, and it is subsequently piped into `bzcat` (a BZip2 utility that decompresses data on STDIN and prints it on STDOUT). `feh -` opens the image viewer `feh` using data from STDIN.

`feh -` is two bytes shorter than the traditional ImageMagick `display` program.

If any bash wizards can help me figure out a way to use the raw binary data instead of having to encode it in hex (`echo -ne` wasn't working right), I'd be forever grateful.

Thanks to kundor for 2 bytes

Comment: Wow, that's pretty creative!

Comment: You can get rid of the spaces around the pipes and `<<` to save four bytes or so.

Comment: you can put `bzcat...` right after the pipe and save a newline

Comment: You can save 121 bytes by using base64 and removing the padding. First line becomes: `base64 -d<<H|bzcat|feh -`.

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, 221 bytes

There must be a way to bring this down, but its not jumping out at me.  Maybe I can find something with coding some of the oft-used constants to variables, like 30, 15, 25, etc.  Possibly it can be done with the `rectMode(CENTER)` taken out, but I think the coordinates will on average get longer, canceling out the savings.

```
size(30,30);background(255);rectMode(CENTER);fill(0);rect(15,5,5,5);rect(15,25,5,5);rect(25,15,5,5);rect(5,25,5,5);rect(25,25,5,5);stroke(99);noFill();rect(5,15,10,30);rect(25,15,10,30);rect(15,5,30,10);rect(15,25,30,10);
```

Ungolfed:

```
//open the tiny window
size(30,30);
//set the background to white
background(255);
//all rectangle coordinates will be relative to their centers, rather than the top left corner
rectMode(CENTER);
//black
fill(0);
//5 rectangles for the glider. Rectangle because "rect" is shorter than "ellipse"
rect(15,5,5,5);
rect(15,25,5,5);
rect(25,15,5,5);
rect(5,25,5,5);
rect(25,25,5,5);
//set border color to gray. 99 because its noticeably gray without being a 3-digit number, saving a byte
stroke(99);
//rectangles will be hollow from now on
noFill();
//draw 4 boxes for the grid lines.  
//Draw a box around the left 1/3 of the window, then the right 1/3, 
//then the top 1/3, and lastly the bottom 1/3
rect(5,15,10,30);
rect(25,15,10,30);
rect(15,5,30,10);
rect(15,25,30,10);
```

Output:
I can't do anything about the gray border in the image, that is the smallest Processing will let me open a window, but the actual image is in the center.  If I were to save that frame of the image, it would only be the 30x30 bit in the middle.

[image: tiny glider]

Comment: Not bad! It doesn't break any rules, the gray around the image *is* technically a border!

Answer (score 1):

## Lua + LÖVE, 264 characters

```lua
l=love
g=l.graphics
g.setLineStyle("rough")function l.draw()g.setBackgroundColor(255,255,255)for i=0,8 do
x=i%3*11+1
y=(i-i%3)/3*11+1
g.setColor(127,127,127)g.rectangle("line",x,y,11,11)if("15678"):find(i)then
g.setColor(0,0,0)g.circle("fill",x+5,y+5,4)end
end
end
```

Sample output:

[image: Glider drawn with Lua and LÖVE]

#### Lua + LÖVE, 241 characters

```lua
l=love
g=l.graphics
function l.draw()g.setBackgroundColor(255,255,255)for i=0,8 do
x=i%3*10+1
y=(i-i%3)/3*10+1
g.setColor(127,127,127)g.rectangle("line",x,y,10,10)if("15678"):find(i)then
g.setColor(0,0,0)g.circle("fill",x+5,y+5,3)end
end
end
```

The question owner not answered yet the [anti-aliasing question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123797/display-the-hacker-logo/124152#comment304123_123797) and some other solutions also have additional gray shades added by the anti-aliasing, so for now this shorter one looks also acceptable.

Sample output:

[image: Glider drawn with Lua and LÖVE - with anti-aliasing]

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 187 bytes (174+13) <strike>205 bytes (192+13)</strike>

```js
a=40,w=80,x=c.getContext`2d`;c=(X,Y)=>{x.beginPath();x.arc(X*a+20,Y*a+20,15,0,7);x.fill()};c(1,0),c(2,1),c(0,2),c(1,2),c(2,2);i=4;while(i--)x.strokeRect((i&1)*a,(i&2)*20,w,w)
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

Ungolfed

```
a = 40,w = 80,
x = c.getContext `2d`;
c = (X, Y) => {
    x.beginPath();
    x.arc(X * a + 20, Y * a + 20, 15, 0, 7);
    x.fill()
};
c(1, 0), c(2, 1), c(0, 2), c(1, 2), c(2, 2);
i = 4;
while (i--) x.strokeRect((i&1)*a, (i&2)*20, w, w)
```

Comment: [191 bytes](https://jsfiddle.net/qdLbwopr/)

Comment: @ThePirateBay nice! I could reduce even further to 187

Answer (score 1):

## [imagegen](https://github.com/MCMastery/imagegen), <strike>167</strike> <strike>154</strike> 55 bytes (non-competing)

*Edit 2*: Added grid draw function

*Edit 1*: Fixed bug where you needed spaces to separate rectangle fill functions. Removed those spaces

[image: output]

```
31x31 F^G910R013,3,5R023,13,5R03,23,5R013,23,5R023,23,5
```

### Running

To run, click the link above to the Github repository and read the usage section. After running imagegen, just paste the code into the console and hit enter. The program will generate an image to `out.png` in the same folder as the EXE.

Just started working on a new image generation golf language today to help me get used to C#. The score will continue to decrease as I add more features (and the answer will hopefully get less boring).

### Explanation

1. Fill image with white background
2. Draw gray grid
3. Draw each black rectangle individually

#### Code explanation

- `31x31` sets image size. If you leave this out it will default to 600x400
- `F^` Fills the image with the color '^'. If you look in ColorCodes.txt in the Github repository, you will see this corresponds to white. This fills the white background.
- `G910` Draws a grid of lines 10 pixels apart with the color '9' which corresponds to #999999 - gray. This draws the gray grid
- `R013,3,5,5` is the fill rectangle function. I use the color '0' (black), and it draws this rectangle at (13,3) with size 5x5.

This is still a major work in progress, just started a couple hours ago

Comment: Not bad, good luck on your language! +1

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl/Tk, 173

```
pack [canvas .c -bg #FFF]
time {.c cr l [incr i 10] 10 $i 40 -f gray;.c cr l 10 $i 40 $i -f gray} 4
lmap x\ y {2 1 3 2 1 3 2 3 3 3} {.c cr o ${x}2 ${y}2 ${x}8 ${y}8 -f #000}
```

[image]

## Tcl/Tk, 188

```
pack [canvas .c -bg #FFF]
lmap i {2 12 22 32} {.c cr l 2 $i 32 $i -f gray;.c cr l $i 2 $i 32 -f gray}
lmap x {13 23 3 13 23} y {3 13 23 23 23} {.c cr o $x $y [incr x 8] [incr y 8] -f #000}
```

[image: hacker logo]

Answer (score 1):

### HTML & CSS, 113 bytes

I started working on this version because of [Octopus' similar answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123797/display-the-hacker-logo/123801#123801).
I've mainly done away with excessive elements and replaced them with CSS-generated pseudo elements.

```css
th{font:5em/.37''}th::after{content:'\2022
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 border><td><th><td><tr><td><td><th><tr><th><th><th
```

Here's another one of **95 bytes** that makes use of x's instead of bullets

```css
*{width:2em;font-size:2em;letter-spacing:-.22em;line-height:.645em
```

```html
☐☒☐ ☐☐☒ ☒☒☒
```

Comment: Your 95-byte solution is invalid as the X's don't take up 40-80% of their boxes.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11 (OpenJDK), 310 bytes

First time golfing, I hope I got it right...

```
()->{new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){int x=20,y=40,z=60;g.fillOval(x,0,x,x);g.fillOval(0,y,x,x);g.fillOval(x,y,x,x);g.fillOval(y,y,x,x);g.fillOval(y,x,x,x);g.setColor(Color.gray);g.drawRect(0,0,z,z);g.drawRect(0,0,z,y);g.drawRect(0,0,z,x);g.drawLine(x,0,x,z);g.drawLine(y,0,y,z);}}.setVisible(2>1);};
```

Opens a window as small as the OS allows that can be dragged open. Also the image is partially hidden behind the window border:

[image]

Here's how it would look like without the border

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11 (OpenJDK), 265 bytes

This is just a golfed version of @mindoverflow's answer, full credit goes to him.
The problem is just that I can't comment yet.

```
()->{new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){int x=20,y=40,z=60,i=3;g.fillOval(x,0,x,x);g.fillOval(y,x,x,x);for(;i-->0;g.fillOval(i*x,y,x,x));g.setColor(Color.gray);for(i=4;i-->1;g.drawRect(0,0,z,i*x));g.drawLine(x,0,x,z);g.drawLine(y,0,y,z);}}.setVisible(2>1);};
```

It looks just like @mindoverflow`s, but by wrapping a couple of method calls into for-loops you can save 45 bytes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>242</s> 236 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;v->new Frame(){{add(new Panel(){public void paint(Graphics g){for(int i=9,t;i-->0;g.setColor(Color.BLACK),g.fillOval(t%3*10+1,t/3*10+1,8,8),g.setColor(Color.GRAY),g.drawRect(i%3*10,i/3*10,10,10))t=i>4?i:1;}});show();}}
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

Screenshot of the actual 30x30 pixels result:

[image]

Screenshot of the ten times larger 300x300 result:

[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;            // Required import for almost everything
v->                           // Method with empty unused parameter and Frame return-type
  new Frame(){                //  Create the Frame
   {                          //   In an inner code-block:
     add(new Panel(){         //    Add a Panel we can draw on:
       public void paint(Graphics g){
                              //     Overwrite its paint method:
         for(int i=9,t;i-->0  //      Loop `i` in the range (9, 0]:
             ;                //        After every iteration:
              g.setColor(Color.BLACK),
                              //         Set the color to black
              g.fillOval(     //         Draw a solid circle:
                t%3*10+1,,    //          At x-coordinate t%3*10 + 1
                t/3*10+1,     //          At y-coordinate t//3*10 + 1
                8,8),         //          Of size 8x8 pixels (80%)
              g.setColor(Color.GRAY),
                              //         Then change the color to gray
              g.drawRect(     //         Draw an open square:
               i%3*10,i/3*10, //          At x,y-coordinate i%3*10, i//3*10
               10,10))        //          Of size 10x10 pixels
           t=i>4?             //       If `i` is 5, 6, 7 or 8:
              i               //        Set `t` to `i`
             :                //       Else:
              1;}});          //        Set `t` to 1 instead
     show();}}                //    And afterwards show the Frame
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 192 bytes

```
„P230D2•1Ù!}c¡”·?I%Úré$(₅È,ï₂¥%_ŸŸ7ÞÈŸÀā5ΩQKÓ<g‹öÖKζΩlá>ÑzHŠ@UY∍ŸµHÔy¥¥çì’hιιkΔ¶Bα±‘êÕá5jθô∊7”ËôAÓÞªx—Ú‘AyQ½ÝYÇD≠z!ÄŸ—'¡Uγ¥!ε+¿þn0^ƵнƵ%X₃8нÜEÃĀ82Îx'IΣн∍óιêZ±иoŽÐθ³ÿIèÉœRuÎ0DBh_ĆûÚ‹ÈûÉW1Ò₁•3в1»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FZBLSwJRAIV/i5AY1MIHoouoFAPFTQZStkgqInuQUAQqBNexx1gklRYpKU4xlBKE6dgMMgn3OC4v8xvuH7Fpd@Ac@D5O@mRza29nMuGksez2OENuTl5dqNrOtqnESZ3@LETsqB2jNTXNhQuIs/jigkBle9JQDdWHBkRDBRnlvawVi6I8t8uJhj6eoqzPWoeQ5nGfCxvNxXiCi7eGSpUwKlkqUxnv@OSkmmIa0w5YhfaDrEM7nDyjjUdI3n2mosfFa5@lgRv0AiijQdsZTiqoWbNANkZ11BO4CvFiM2fDuaFanYNKcdalso0pM3SI3yPnxlgx9bFiX@NCwW/qeFlCYUT8bpQyjgh7M3VLDF2mob1OO6aaNnTcMZV2MYzgA0WjvHKKkjMUTCVHlxj8szWIViiuuvDAhbz1mMf8dtHBZPIH) Outputs as a plain PGM.

## Output (enlarged)

[image: Hacker Emblem]

Actual output size is 30x30.

---

```
„P230D2•...•3в1»  # trimmed program
„P2               # push literal
   30             # push literal...
     D            # twice
      2           # push literal
             в    # push list of base-10 values of base...
            3     # literal...
             в    # digits of...
       •...•      # 427541225056090484779390842559962277535356179915664563570852766785644784557400927981185964800417173067134497361607731953969389383383710765821962940570130871145015821269287935868419374755244532042313674055574776583016673806369314382290002772542995095921556681406703587909310388486054711832330497506948107550678784337269482395576308349400348694552486117428881164944824595892240209460307603873442854698425661641130046746477556925533...
              1   # push literal
               »  # join stack by newlines, joining lists on the stack by spaces
                  # implicit output
```

Comment: does converting the dots to perfect squares help with compression?

Comment: @Razetime I already noticed, thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 0):

### CSS+HTML, 31+95=126 bytes

This is a merge of the solutions from [Octopus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123843/10875) and [Uriel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123801/10875). I figured Uriel solution could benefit from using `•` instead of using `div`, and Octopus solution could benefit from using the `border` attribute instead of setting it in CSS.

So, in the spirit of [xkcd/927](https://xkcd.com/927/) I made another answer instead of commenting to either of them.

```css
td{line-height:.4;font-size:3em
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 border=1px><tr><td><td>•<td><tr><td><td><td>•<tr><td>•<td>•<td>•
```

Comment: "You will display the emblem with graphical output but no ASCII art."

Answer (score 0):

## SVG, <s>487</s> <s>449</s> <s>355</s> 301 Bytes

**Compressed Version:**

```
<svg><g id=g><path d=M1,1L1,13L13,13L13,1Z id=r fill=none stroke=gray /><use href=#r x=12 /><use href=#r x=24 /></g><use href=#g /><use href=#g y=12 /><use href=#g y=24 /><circle id=c cx=19 cy=7 r=5 /><use href=#c x=12 y=12 /><use href=#c x=-12 y=24 /><use href=#c x=0 y=24 /><use href=#c x=12 y=24 />
```

**Special Thanks:**

*@Meyer* - Thanks for taking off 54 bytes!

*@ovs* - Thanks for bringing up compliance issue with radius of circle

**Uncompressed Version Code Snippet:**

```html
<svg>
    <g id=g>
        <path d=M1,1L1,13L13,13L13,1Z id=r fill=none stroke=gray />
        <use href=#r x=12 />
        <use href=#r x=24 />
    </g>
    <use href=#g />
    <use href=#g y=12 />
    <use href=#g y=24 />
    <circle id=c cx=19 cy=7 r=5 />
    <use href=#c x=12 y=12 />
    <use href=#c x=-12 y=24 />
    <use href=#c x=0 y=24 />
    <use href=#c x=12 y=24 />
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS+HTML = 13+83 = 96 bytes**

```css
td{width:21px
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 border><td><td>⬛<td><tr><td>⬛<td><tr><td>⬛<td>⬛<td>⬛
```

*Thanks to @mbomb007*

**CSS+HTML = 38+83 = 121 bytes [No Unicode]**

CSS

```
p{width:8px;height:8px;background:#000
```

HTML

```
<table cellspacing=0 border><td><td><p><td><tr><td><p><td><tr><td><p><td><p><td><p>
```

Tested on:

Chrome 72.0.3626.121

### [image]

**CSS+HTML = 38+87 = 125  bytes [No Unicode]**

CSS

```
p{width:8px;height:8px;background:#000
```

HTML

```
<table cellspacing=0 border><td><td><p><td><tr><td><td><td><p><tr><td><p><td><p><td><p>
```

Tested on:
Chrome 72.0.3626.121

[image]

Comment: Nice. How about [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/m64nz5v2/) for [87 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%3Ctable%20cellspacing%3D0%20border%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctd%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B)?

Comment: @mbomb007 Nice. [This](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%3Ctable%20cellspacing=0%20border%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctd%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctd%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B%3Ctd%3E%E2%AC%9B) is your version updated. Only 83 bytes. But I think it's against the rules _Each grid-box in the grid will be the same size._

Comment: Your first one does the exact same thing (see your first image), but this shorter version doesn't appear to be square, which is a requirement.

Answer (score -2):

## SVG/CSS, 700 bytes

```css
rect{fill:white;stroke:grey;stroke-width:1}
```

```html
<svg width=48 height=48 ><rect width=16 height=16 /><rect x=16 width=16 height=16 /><circle cx=24 cy=8 r=6 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=black /><rect x=32 width=16 height=16 /><rect y=16 width=16 height=16 /><rect x=16 y=16 width=16 height=16 /><rect x=32 y=16 width=16 height=16 /><circle cx=40 cy=24 r=6 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=black /><rect y=32 width=16 height=16 /><circle cx=8 cy=40 r=6 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=black /><rect x=16 y=32 width=16 height=16 /><circle cx=24 cy=40 r=6 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=black /><rect x=32 y=32 width=16 height=16 /><circle cx=40 cy=40 r=6 stroke=black stroke-width=1 fill=black /></svg>
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm not an expert in SVG, but I'm fairly certain that you can remove some unnecessary bytes (indentation, plus the `<-- something -->` lines that appear to be comments).

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jm4begvd/1/) is a golfed version at 700 bytes using svg and css. Feel free to edit it in.