# Place a glider!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, grid, game-of-life

This:

[image]

is a *Glider*.

In Conway's Game of Life, the [glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(Conway%27s_Life)) is a famous pattern that rapidly traverses across the board. For today's challenge, we are going to draw an ASCII art Game of Life Board, and place a glider on it.

The board we are starting with is this:

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

This board is made up entirely of pipes `|` and underscores `_`, and is 10x10. You must write a program or function that takes in two integers, 'x' and 'y', and outputs this same board with a glider at those coordinates. For example, if you had a glider at position `(1, 1)` (0-indexed), you must output the following:

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|*|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|*|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|*|*|*|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

You can assume that the glider will never be placed out of bounds, so both x and y will always be in the `[0-7]` range. You may also choose to take the coordinates 1-indexed, but you must specify this in your answer. In this, case the inputs will always be in the `[1-8]` range. Here are some examples (all 0-indexed):

```
0, 0:
|_|*|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|*|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|*|*|*|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|

7, 7:
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|*|*|

7, 4:
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|*|*|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|

5, 2:
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|*|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|*|*|*|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

As usual, you may take your IO in any reasonable format. This includes, but is not limited to a string with newlines, an array of strings, a 2d array of strings, or writing to a file/STDOUT. You may also choose what order to take *x* and *y* in.

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), standard loopholes are banned, and make the shortest code that you can!

Comment: Can we change which corner identifies the glider's position?

Comment: @StephenS No, the coordinates should Identify where the top left corner of the glider starts.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123797/61563)

Comment: `the glider is a famous pattern that slowly traverses across the boar.`. Slowly? It is the fastest diagonal moving object in GoL. It reaches 1/4 of the speed of light.

Comment: @Christoph, good point,we can observe that it's length does not appear to contract in the direction of travel, but I don't know any way of measuring it's mass at relativistic speeds.

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
20*+'|_'5E:21:I$)42b' 34'Q+(
```

The code contains unprintable chars. Input is 0-based. **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38hAS1u9Jl7d1NXKyNDKU0XTxChJnUdOwdhEPVBb4/9/cy4TAA)**

Answer (score 6):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>31</s>, 30 bytes

```
10O±°_|ÀGjjÀ|3r*kr*kh.Í*ü_/|&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39DA/9DGQxvia6QPN7hnZR1uqDEu0soGogy9w71ah/fE69eo/f//3@i/EQA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 3130 4fb1 b05f 7c1b c047 6a6a c07c 3372  10O.._|..Gjj.|3r
00000010: 2a6b 722a 6b68 2ecd 2afc 5f2f 7c26       *kr*kh..*._/|&
```

This takes input as program arguments, and 1-indexed.

Explanation:

```
10O                         " On the following 10 lines, insert:
   ±°_                      "   10 '_' characters
      |                     "   And a '|'
       <esc>                " Return to normal mode
            ÀG              " Go to the a'th line
              jj            " Move down two lines
                À|          " Go to the b'th column
                  3r*       " and replace the next 3 characters with asterisks
                     k      " Move up a line
                      r*    " And replace this char with an asterisk
                        kh  " Move up a line and to the left
                          . " And repeat the last change we performed (replace with asterisk)
                            "
Í                           " On every line, substitute:
 *                          "   An asterisk
  ü                         "   OR
   _                        "   An underscore
    /                       " With:
     |&                     "   A bar followed by the matched pattern
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>165</s> <s>144</s> <s>138</s> <s>135</s> <s>129</s> <s>127</s> 125 bytes

```java
x->y->{var r="";for(int i=0,j;++i<11;r+="|\n")for(j=0;j<10;)r+=i==x&j==y|i==x+1&++j==y|i==x+2&j<y+3&j>=y?"|*":"|_";return r;}
```

1-indexed.

-14 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lY9NT4MwHMbvfIp/eiDUjgZmNMZSvJl48LSjGlMZW1qhkFLIyOCzY4kTE2Myvf2el8PzKNGJUG3fJ1nWlbGgnKatlQXdtTqzstL0/gTM87JCNA08CqmPHkBjhZUZfOXJg7b5PjerX5yNNVLv0xQy4DAdwrQP02MnDBiOENtVJpDaguTRSjFCZBLHzBCOhmeN8JwqHjGVxBHDzpacH3zFeT/MRGKfkG@19lXSk0tfpby/Q8MFukXDK2Imt63RYNg4uR8AdftWuO2nC10lt1C6W8Hn0KcXgeeHAJu@sXlJq9bS2iW20EFGRV0XfbDGC2B2rhzjBc6Xb/AC/yhf/aF8/WPz6I3TBw)

```java
x->y->{               // Method with two integer parameters and String return-type
  var r="";           //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(int i=0,j;i<10  //  Loop over the rows:
      ;               //    After every iteration:
       r+="|\n")      //     Append a "|" and newline to the result-String
    for(j=0;++j<11;)  //   Inner loop over the columns:
      r+=i==x&j==y|i==x+1&++j==y|i==x+2&j<y+3&j>=y?
                      //    If this coordinate should contain a '*'
        "|*"          //     Append "|*" to the result-String
       :              //    Else:
        "|_");        //     Append "|_" to the result-String
  return r;}          //  Return the result-String
```

Comment: Explanation has different code than your answer?  Look at first assignment to r.

Comment: @Computronium Oops, thanks for noticing, fixed. The bye-count was correct, explanation was correct, TIO-link was correct, but the actual answer was still the old incorrect one..

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 67 bytes

```perl
sub{map{($_-join('',@_)~~[1,12,20..22]?"|*":"|_")."|\n"x/9$/}0..99}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NKk6N7GgWkMlXjcrPzNPQ11dxyFes64u2lDH0EjHyEBPz8go1l6pRkvJSqkmXklTT6kmJk@pQt9SRb8WKGlpWfvfmqugKDOvREFNJU3DQMdAU0dBCagEWdRcxxyLqAlWUVMdI5jofwA)

Input Parameters: y, x

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
ȷ2b1
Ḍ+“£Æßæç‘Ṭ+¢s⁵j3;0$€Fṭ0ị“_*¶|”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AUYAuf//yLcyYjEK4biMK@KAnMKjw4bDn8Omw6figJjhuawrwqJz4oG1ajM7MCTigqxG4bmtMOG7i@KAnF8qwrZ84oCd////Niwz)

**How it works**

```
ȷ2b1                             - the literal [1,1,1,1,...,1,1,1] with 100 elements
Ḍ+“£Æßæç‘Ṭ+¢s⁵j3;0$€Fṭ0ị“_*¶|”   - input (x,y)
Ḍ                                - convert (x,y) to 10*x+y
 +                               - add, to get the five "*" positions,
  “£Æßæç‘                        - the literal [2,13,21,22,23]
         Ṭ                       - return an array with those positions as truthy elements
          +¢                    - Now we format: pad to length 100 with the above literal
            s⁵j3                 - add newlines (represented by 3) to each set of 10
                ;0$€F            - add pipes (represented by 0) to each
                     ṭ0          - add a 0 to the beginning
                       ị“_*¶|”   - index into the string “_*¶|”
```

Comment: How do you type/generate your programs?

Comment: @RobotCaleb : generally copy-pasting from the [Jelly codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page). I run them at the [TIO nexus](https://tio.run/#jelly) when not at my main machine, and a clone of the [Jelly repository](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) at my main computer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 151 bytes

Will golf more.

```python
def f(x,y):r,x=[list('|_'*10+'|')for i in[1]*10],x*2;r[y][x+3]=r[y+1][x+5]=r[y+2][x+1]=r[y+2][x+3]=r[y+2][x+5]='*';print'\n'.join(''.join(i)for i in r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Tc1NCsIwEAXgfU@R3eRnkCS1FCw9SQxuNBCRVGIXKfTuMdWiWc33Hg8mX2@OOJpwYaeIaTQP/5oprBfgSgpYgbkpEk98MMqWymLieohmsSaJ1o5FQm3uvtabVeW2ctkAh@EZfZjhHOBwn3ygsF//e0Uiy45KlKz5bBtHe@zrcPwHjd0e8hs)

Comment: If you're willing to switch to Python 3, you can save 3 bytes by using `[*'|_'*10+'|']` instead of the `list()` call.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 88 bytes

```
->\x,\y{(^10 »*»i X+ ^10).map:{<|* |_>[$_!=
(1-2i|2-i|0|1|2)+x+y*i+2i]~"|
"x(.re==9)}}
```

- Complex numbers are used to represent the coordinates.
- `^10 »*» i X+ ^10` generates the grid of all complex numbers with integer components from zero through nine.
- Returns a list of strings, each one holding one line.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that Perl utilizes non-ASCII. What does `»` do? How is it encoded?

Comment: It's just Unicode's RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET, U+00BB, encoded in UTF-8.  In Perl 6 it can just as well be written as two angle brackets, `>>`, but that's the same number of bytes as the guillemet so for golfing I prefer the latter as it looks a little classier IMHO.  As for what it does, it transforms the operator it surrounds into a "hyperoperator" that applies pairwise to the lists or values on either side.  Here, it multiplies each element of the range `0-9` by `i`, giving `0, i, 2i, ..., 9i`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 87 bytes

```ruby
->x,y{[a=(b='|_')*10+?|]*y+%w(|_|*|_ |_|_|* |*|*|*).map{|r|b*x+r+b*(7-x)+?|}+[a]*(7-y)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165Cp7I6OtFWI8lWvSZeXVPL0EDbviZWq1JbtVyjJr5GqyZeAUgBGQpANhBq6uUmFlTXFNUkaVVoF2knaWmY61ZoAvXUakcnxoJ4lZq1/wtKS4oV0qINdAxidexj8rigfHMdcxS@iY4Jmjwq30jHFMz/DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

```js
x=>y=>eval('for(i=0,o="";i<101;o+=((d=i-x-y*10)==1|d==12|d>19&d<23?"|*":"|_")+(++i%10?"":`|\n`))o')
```

Takes input via currying: `f(5)(2)` for x=5, y=2. Coordinates are zero-indexed.

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
x=>y=>eval('for(i=0,o="";i<101;o+=((d=i-x-y*10)==1|d==12|d>19&d<23?"|*":"|_")+(++i%10?"":`|\n`))o')

xi.oninput=yi.oninput=_=>O.innerHTML=f(xi.value)(yi.value)
O.innerHTML=f(xi.value=5)(yi.value=2)
```

```html
<style>*{font-family:Consolas;}input{width:2.5em;}</style>
x: <input id="xi" type="number" min="0" max="7">,
y: <input id="yi" type="number" min="0" max="7">
<pre id="O">
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte if split the sum https://tio.run/##DcrRCoMgFIDhdzmwpZlD29WqUy8yWJY2HNIZNaLAd3fBz3f1f8xm1nHx358czOCCnMm6NGHasT2wdZsJLJtoYR5VQQhQ@0YrXZNAZtHLXR65VhxRR3tSRtvqx9U25b2DmEMF8QXFOQvhL1p1AFUfn3PPKeNppHml4G6B3mxiip/xOv0B

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 40 bytes

```apl
'*'@((⍳2)∘×¨⎕∘+¨⍸⊤1 5 3)⊢'|',⍨10 20⍴'|_'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97b@6lrqDhsaj3s1Gmo86ZhyefmjFo76pQJY2kNG741HXEkMFUwVjzUddi9Rr1HUe9a4wNFAwMnjUu0W9Jl4dZMT/NC5zBXMA)

A full program, accepting x and y as input.

Calculate coordinates, and uses `@` to modify them.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 97 bytes

```python
def f(x,y):
 b=(["|_"]*10+["|\n"])*10
 for c in[1,13,22,23,24]:b[c+11*y+x]="|*"
 return"".join(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcdBCsMgEEDRvaeQWTlmKGpSAoGcJJWCaaTpQoNYiJC722wK7ebz31byM4a21sfiuRc7FRwYd6OY4LiDlVo1590CWDyfcR8Tn/kaJk26JWPInO3s4Ka50VqWZrcjHBIYT0t@pwBwecU1CId1S2vIwgtFCpF91VP/p@5Hhq6I9QM)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>115</s> 113 bytes

```
x(a="|_"~Table~10~Table~10;(a[[##]]="|*")&@@(#+x)&/@({{0,1,2,2,2},{1,2,0,1,2}});""<>Riffle[#<>"|"&/@a,"\n"])
```

where

This takes input in `{row, col}` format, and is 1-indexed, but can be turned into 0-indexed without adding bytes.

Some notes:

1. `\n` is a newline character, takes 1 byte.
2. `` is `\[Function]`, takes 3 bytes.
3. `` is `\[Transpose]`, takes 3 bytes.

Note that "array of string" is allowed, so I can just remove `Riffle`, gives

### Mathematica, <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```
x(a="|_"~Table~10~Table~10;(a[[##]]="|*")&@@(#+x)&/@({{0,1,2,2,2},{1,2,0,1,2}});#<>"|"&/@a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 96 bytes

```hs
r=[0..9]
x#y=['|':(r>>=(\i->[last$'_':['*'|elem(i-x,j-y)$zip[1,2,0,1,2][0,1,2,2,2]],'|']))|j<-r]
```

Takes in two integers (`x` and `y`) and returns a list of `String`s, i.e. a 2D list of type `[[Char]]`.

---

**Test suite:**

```hs
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (x, y) = (read $ args !! 0, read $ args !! 1)
    mapM_ putStrLn (x#y)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 133 bytes

```python
x,y=input()
a=[[z for z in'_'*10]for o in'|'*10]
b=a[y+2]
a[y][x+1]=a[y+1][x+2]=b[x]=b[x+1]=b[x+2]="*"
for b in a:print o+o.join(b)+o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNCsMgEITvPsWSS34MpUqhUPBJlqXoodQeXAkGNPTdbbSXmfm@w8SS3hx0rXktxoe4p2kW1iAe8OINDvBhfI6LulJDbvjtKJyxWKQmcRZhloq6UG1rMg5zj@bdXw3LINqLO1/APuLmQwKWfPmwD5ObJdd6X28/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/), 85 bytes

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVNBw0jB0FjByFDByEjByFjTPTpTW8VQxSjWVosLqqDaUE/P0MCgVrOgKDOvJE0hpkalGqgs1ko3vlZNTUMjU9XQQFOzpsbGxiam5v///2b/zQA)

```zsh
for i (2 13 21 22 23)G[i+$1$2]=*
for i ({1..100})printf \|${G[i]:-_}&&((i%10))||<<<\|
```

<sub>*Saved 12 bytes by moving the glider char `*` assignments to a function.
Saved another 4 bytes by removing the function and adding a ternary to the `printf` stuff (at the expense of readability!). Saved another 7 by inlining some data instead of constructing an array. Saved another 10 by simplifying some expressions. Removed `{}` for another -1. Saved 11 by using [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) `${name:-word}` instead of convoluted ascii logic.*

<s>[130 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIUNBo9pQT8/QwKBW0z06I9Y2nivFVsVQxUjBPdpIOyXWVgvIMDSGsYwM4Sy4rBFElgtkXCaScdUFRZl5JWkKMTUq7tGZsdYaGpmqhgY2hpqaamo2NjYxNda1////N/lvCgA)</s> <s>[118 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIUNBo9pQT8/QwKBW0z06I9Y2nitXA8hSMdROibXV4kqxVTFUMbLOVQBhQ2MQwxBEgIWMuUBGZCIZUV1QlJlXkqYQU6PiHp0Za62hkalqaGBjqKmppmZjYxNTY137//9/k/@mAA)</s> <s>[114 bytes](https://tio.run/##LckxDsIwDADAnVdYqqlskKrYASFICurUR6RZK7IAKkykeXtYuPW@73utQ08KYkEFVEEtu/m5QALCgceAIe1RUGPsd5t/ZOk6MaZwfi3p8ZlhWjFTw0iEzRhSvJrbQS/nI3NxRGkrxgtz23rvp9WVWqutpx8)</s> <s>[107 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcoxDsIwDADAnVdYqqlskKrYASFogLGPSLNWZCmoMJHm7Wbh5vu@H2bTc4EMpCAeVEAV1PMQMeY9CmpK193mf4p0nThXubyWPH8mGFcs1DASYTPEnG7uftDL@chce6K8FReEuW1DCOPaVzPzdvoB)</s> <s>[97 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoMwDADAnVdYIpVsIaHYgaEQxMgjgBU1C1S0U5O83WXg5vt9XqrbcUIAFGAHwiAC4miaQ2XYyDpwcYfIdc3WZorvM@zfDZZkIpZkEK@9jo10z5Yo94jhwZYoJe/9krKqNur@)</s> <s>[96 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVNBw0jB0FjByFDByEjByFjTPTpTW8VQxSjW1pALqqDaUE/P0MCgVrOgKDOvJE0hpkalWkNZU0VDA6g41t7EyMrSVFOzVk1NQyNT1dBAU7OmxsbGJqbm////Zv/NAA)</s></sub>

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 98 bytes

Based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124047/116593)

```
x=>y=>eval('for(i=0,o="";i<101;o+=(d=i-x-y*10)==1|d==12|d>19&d<23?"|*":"|_",o+=++i%10?"":`|\n`)o')
```

We can save 1 byte if use `o+=a,o+=b` instead of `o+=(a)+(b)`

Try it:

```js
f=
x=>y=>eval('for(i=0,o="";i<101;o+=(d=i-x-y*10)==1|d==12|d>19&d<23?"|*":"|_",o+=++i%10?"":`|\n`)o')

xi.oninput=yi.oninput=_=>O.innerHTML=f(xi.value)(yi.value)
O.innerHTML=f(xi.value=5)(yi.value=2)
```

```html
<style>*{font-family:Consolas;}input{width:2.5em;}</style>
x: <input id="xi" type="number" min="0" max="7">,
y: <input id="yi" type="number" min="0" max="7">
<pre id="O">
```

## JavaScript, 101 bytes

This answer may be more efficient with another pattern

```
x=>y=>eval("for(i=0,s='';i<101;s+=[1,12,20,21,22].includes(i-x-y*10)?'|*':'|_',s+=++i%10?'':`|\n`)s")
```

Try it:

```js
f=
x=>y=>eval("for(i=0,s='';i<101;s+=[1,12,20,21,22].includes(i-x-y*10)?'|*':'|_',s+=++i%10?'':`|\n`)s")

xi.oninput=yi.oninput=_=>O.innerHTML=f(xi.value)(yi.value)
O.innerHTML=f(xi.value=5)(yi.value=2)
```

```html
<style>*{font-family:Consolas;}input{width:2.5em;}</style>
x: <input id="xi" type="number" min="0" max="7">,
y: <input id="yi" type="number" min="0" max="7">
<pre id="O">
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
LIΖ|_ΟL∙.«."¾'┼ΞΧ⌠²‘5nž
```

note: this expects input to be 1-indexed

Explanation:

```
LI                       push 11
  Ζ|_                    push "|" and "_"
     Ο                   make an altrenates string [with 11 separators, which are "|" and parts "_"]
      L∙                 get an array of 10 of those
        .«               take input and multiply by 2 (x pos)
          .              take input (y pos)
           "¾'┼ΞΧ⌠²‘     push "_|*|__|_|**|*|*" - the glider in the map
                    5n   split into an array with items of length 5
                      ž  replace in the 1st [grid] array at positions [inp1*2, inp2] to 2nd array [glider]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＵＯ²¹χ|_Ｊ×Ｎ²Ｎ“ "}ＩyE%%mＬＢＭφ/”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98/KSc/L13DyFBHwdBAR0GpJl5J05rLqzS3ICRfQ0vDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0fBCIhRhIBqA4oy80o0gBprtGriY/KANJAFpLVAEGjY///mXOb/dcv@6xbnAAA) Link to verbose mode for description.

Comment: I'm disappointed that Charcoal isn't, well... ASCII-only ;)

Comment: You can remove the `|_` before the `\n` to save a compressed byte. (I tried several different ways of printing the glider but none saved any bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 97 bytes

```python
def f(x,y):
 b=(["|_"]*10+["|\n"])*10
 for c in[1,13,22,23,24]:b[c+11*y+x]="|*"
 return"".join(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcdBCsMgEEDRvaeQWTlxKGpTAoGcJJVC0kjThQYxECF3t24K7ebz35bTK3hTynNx3ImDMvaMT4MY4XyAbbSS9e4eLNZn3IXIZ776UZO@kjFkalvbT@MstW6yPOwAZwOMxyXt0QNc3mH1YsKyxdUn4YQihci@6qj7U/sjQzfE8gE)

Answer (score 0):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), <s>113</s> 107 bytes

Uses 0-indexing.

```
INPUT x,y
s=11*y+x
FOR i=1TO 110
?"|"+CHR$(95+53*((i=s+2)+(i=s+14)-(i>s+22)*(i<s+26))+85*(i/11=i\11));
NEXT
```

We model the grid as 110 `|`s each followed by some character, for which we calculate the ASCII code:

- Every 11th character is a newline (character code 95 - 85 = 10)
- If we calculate the start index of the glider as `s = 11 * y + x`, then indices `s + 2`, `s + 14`, `s + 23`, `s + 24`, and `s + 25` are asterisks (character code 95 - 53 = 42)
- The rest are underscores (character code 95)

---

Original version using `LOCATE` (1-indexed):

```
INPUT x,y
CLS
FOR i=0TO 9
FOR j=0TO 9
?"|_";
NEXT
?"|
NEXT
LOCATE y,2*x+2
?"*
LOCATE,2*x+4
?"*
LOCATE,2*x
?"*|*|*
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
|_Ａ×|＋Ａ＊ *¶  *¶***∙＊┘«╶╋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTdDXyV1RkYyMSVENyU3QyV1RkYwQiV1RkYyMSV1RkYwQSUyMColQjYlMjAlMjAqJUI2KioqJXUyMjE5JXVGRjBBJXUyNTE4JUFCJXUyNTc2JXUyNTRC,i=NiUwQTM_,v=8)

Takes 1-indexed position in form

```
x
y
```

as input.

Only beaten by [dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima)['s SOGL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124048/78186) at time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 25 (or 24?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„|_ти„|*•A|,•₂вI+ǝTôJ€Ć»
```

0-based indexing.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8mviLTRd2gBhajxoWOdboAMlHTU0XNnl6aR@fG3J4i9ejpjVH2g7t/v8/2lDHMBYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6fx/1DCvJv5i04UdIIbWo4ZFjjU6QPJRU9OFTZVe2sfnhhze4vWoac2RtkO7/@sc2mb/PzraQMcgVifaUMcQSJrrmINJEyBpqmMUGwsA).

Could be 1 byte less (the `J`) if we could take the input-coordinates joined together as single integer:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8mviLTRd2gBhajxoWOdboAMlHTU0XNnlqH58bcniL16OmNUfaDu3@/9/QEAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6fx/1DCvJv5i04UdIIbWo4ZFjjU6QPJRU9OFTZXax@eGHN7i9ahpzZG2Q7v/6xzaZv8/2sBAx9BQx9xcx9xEx9QoFgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
„|_            # Push string "|_"
   ти          # Repeat it 100 times as list of strings
„|*            # Push string "|*"
   •A|,•       # Push compressed integer 681976
        ₂в     # Convert it to base-26 as list: [1,12,20,21,22]
          IJ   # Push the input-pair, and join it together to an integer
            +  # Add it to each value in the list [1,12,20,21,22]
„|*          ǝ # Insert the "|*" string at those (0-based) indices to the list of "|_"
Tô             # Split the list into 10 parts of 10 strings each
  J            # Join each inner list together to a string
   €           # Map over each line:
    Ć          # Enclose; append its own head (the "|")
     »         # Join the list of strings by newlines
               # (After which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•A|,•` is `681976` and `•A|,•₂в` is `[1,12,20,21,22]`.